# Do I not understand the flex-grow property?

Tags: css, flexbox, flex-grow

I'm afraid I must not understand flex-grow. If you jump to the JSFiddle below - the way I understand it, `.big` should be three times the size of the other `.flex-item`. As you can see, not so. Why?

http://jsfiddle.net/nrur6mmo/

```css
.flex-container {
    display:flex;
    padding:0 20%;
}
.flex-item {
    flex-grow:1;
    list-style-type:none;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.big {
    flex-grow:3;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
    <li class="flex-item big">Why isn't this exactly three times the size of the other one?</li>
    <li class="flex-item">Not really working like expected I don't think...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: related: [flex-grow not sizing flex items as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34644807/3597276)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You have to specify a value for `flex-basis` as well (not specifying this property causes behaviour similar to using the initial value, [auto](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/images/rel-vs-abs-flex.svg)).

Add `flex-basis: 0;` to both children or just set it with the [shorthand](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-property):

```
.flex-item {
    flex: 1; /* flex-basis is 0 if omitted */
}
.big {
    flex-grow: 3;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEcBa

Comment: I know this answer is old, but it would help to provide a short description on why flex-grow needs a relationship with flex-basis.

Answer (score 34):

Flex-grow is commonly misunderstood in this way.  Flex-grow only controls how the left over space is distributed between flex items, not how big they are in proportion to each other.

What you're looking for is really just this:

```
.flex-item {
  width: 25%;
  list-style-type:none;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.big {
  width: 75%;
}
```

See also

- [Flex-grow not working as expected (flex items don't have the widths I expect)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927302/flex-not-showing-correctly-in-ie-or-chrome)
- [In what circumstances is flex-shrink applied to flex elements and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224732/in-what-circumstances-flex-shrink-is-applied-to-the-flex-elements-and-how-it-wor)

Comment: That contradicts to the top answer where the proportion is set to 1:3, doesn't it?

Answer (score 13):

Authors are encouraged to control flexibility using the flex shorthand rather than with flex-grow directly, as the shorthand correctly resets any unspecified components to accommodate common uses.

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#propdef-flex-grow

```
.flex-item {
   flex: 1;
}
.big {
   flex: 3;
}
```

This is a working example

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjZYPV

Comment: Some explanation here of what is actually being set would be helpful.

Comment: This will work because it will set the flex-basis as 0%

Answer (score 0):

Something related: **Order matters.** For example:

html:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="el el-1">One</div>
    <div class="el el-2">two</div>
    <div class="el el-3">three</div>
    <div class="el el-4">four</div>
    <div class="el el-5">five</div>
    <div class="el el-6">six</div>
    <div class="el el-7">seven</div>
    <div class="el el-8">eight</div>
 </div>
```

css:

```
 .container {
     display: flex;
 }
```

The following style **works**:

```
 .el {
    flex-grow: 1;
 }

 .el-4 {
    flex-grow: 3;
 }
```

But if you change the order, it will **NOT** work:

```
 .el-4 {
    flex-grow: 3;
 }

 .el {
    flex-grow: 1;
 }
```