# What are the differences between flex-grow and width?

Tags: css, flexbox

I've started using the flexbox recently and there often comes the situation where I need to distribute space on the main axis between elements.

I often hesitate between `width` and `flex-grow`. For example, if I want one item to measure 2 measures, and the other 1 measure, adding up to 100%, I have two choices. I can either set `width: 66.6%` and `width: 33.3%`, or `flex-grow: 2` and `flex-grow: 1`.

Sometimes if I want one element to grow the rest of the space, I can either do `width: 100%` or `flex-grow: 1`.

How do I choose? What are the differences/considerations in using width vs. flex-grow?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`width` and `flex-grow` are two entirely different CSS properties.

The `width` property is used for defining the width of elements.

The `flex-grow` property is used for distributing free space in a flex container. This property doesn't apply a specific length to an element, like the `width` property. It simply allows a flex item to consume whatever space may be available.

> Sometimes if I want one element to grow the rest of the space, I can either do `width: 100%` or `flex-grow: 1`. How do I choose?

Yes, if there is one element in the row, `width: 100%` and `flex-grow: 1` may have the same effect (depending on `padding`, `border` and `box-sizing` settings).

But what if there are two elements, and you want the second one to take the remaining space? With a sibling in the container, `width: 100%` causes an overflow. I guess you can do something like this:

```
width: calc(100% - width of sibling);
```

But what if the sibling's width is dynamic or unknown? `calc` is no longer an option.

The quick and easy solution is `flex-grow: 1`.

---

While `width` and `flex-grow` are apples-to-oranges, `width` and `flex-basis` are apples-to-apples.

The `flex-basis` property sets the initial main size of a flex item and is similar to `width`.

- [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)

For the differences between `flex-basis` and `flex-grow` see:

- [flex-grow not sizing flex items as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34644807/3597276)