# Break flexbox if a new container is introduced

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm wondering how I can break the `flex` row and start a new one. I was hoping the `display:flex` would break it, but it does not.

[image: wish]

```css
.dflex {
  display:flex;
}

.flexitem {
  flex:6;
}



/* irrelevant styles */

.dflex {
  border:2px solid red;
  margin:4px;
}

.flexitem {
  border:2px solid black;
  margin:4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dflex">
  <div class="flexitem">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="flexitem">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="dflex">
    <div class="flexitem">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worth remembering that the `flex-grow` property does not necessarily equal width. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733955/width-vs-flex-grow-in-flexbox

Comment: _offtopic_, just out of curiosity: why you use `flex:6`?

Comment: @blonfu I'm trying to build my own grid System. For this `flex:1` would've worked, but elements have flex width based on the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `flex-wrap: wrap;` and `width: 100%;` to your `.dflex` class.

```css
.dflex {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  border:2px solid red;
  margin:4px;
}

.flexitem {
  border:2px solid black;
  margin:4px;
  flex: 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="dflex">
  <div class="flexitem">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="flexitem">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="dflex">
    <div class="flexitem">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```