# issue with flexbox columns

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flex grid with equal columns, but in some of them i have some padding. It appears that this breaks the columns width.

I tried to add the padding to an inner wrapper, but this won't work for me as its percent based.

```
.grid{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.column {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  &.padd{
    padding: 0 5%;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/heyapo/8qntbj3c/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply `flex-grow` or `flex-basis` do not equal `width`.

Detailed explanation [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733955/width-vs-flex-grow-in-flexbox): by Michael_B.

Padding will add to the dimensions of the element receiving it and the *other* elements will resolve their sizes accordingly.

If you want to use width...use width (and box-sizing).

```css
.grid {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.column {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
}
padd {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column padd"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Another solution, depending on limitations, is to use `box-sizing: border-box`. This then allows padding to be included in the width of the container.