# some weird thing with flexbox and flex-grow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I dont seem to understand how the flex-grow works.

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k89twr8e/

The `flex-grow` is not right and i cant find the appropriate values  so the first 2 green box borders align with the one to it's right... The first 2 is ok but the rest are now.

It is something to do with the correct `flex-grow` values for the `.wrap`, `.child` and `.separator`

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Flex-grow is not the same as height/width. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733955/what-are-the-differences-between-flex-grow-and-width

Answer (score 0):

Each column is completely unaware of the size/position of the content in other columns, so I don't think this is going to work like you want it to.

Flex-grow defines the ability to grow *if necessary*, to distribute the space in a particular row/column, and then those numbers just define a ratio relationship with the other elements in that particular column. (example: an element with `flex-grow:4` will be 4x the size of an element with `flex-grow:1`)

That "*if necessary*" part comes into play with your first column. Since initially `.container` doesn't have a defined height, there's no extra space to be distributed. So each element is slotted into the column at their default height, which in this case would be the line-height of the `li`

Below is a visual representation that hopefully helps clarify how the sizes of things are being determined.

[image]

Comment: *... (example: an element with `flex-grow:4` will be 4x the size of an element with `flex-grow:1`)* ... that's not necessarily true.

Comment: An element with `flex-grow:4` *will consume 4x the available free space* of an element with `flex-grow:1`.

Comment: If you're interested, here's a more complete explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34644807/3597276

Comment: thank you for your explanation @brice shatzer. but do you have any solution?.. i mean if i add a fix height on the parent will it work?