# Setting flex css with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

I"m trying to set the flex css property of image containers to the aspect ratio of the image.  I want the flex css to be in form `flex: 1.798245` with no px or 1 1 1px.

Using jQuery css() method it keeps setting it to `flex: 1 1 1.798245px`

```
//gallery flex
$('.gallery-item').each(function(){
  var value = $("img", this).width() / $("img", this).height();
  $(this).css("flex", value);
});
```

How should I pass value to css() to get the result I want?

Comment: Flex-grow etc are **not the same as width**. If you want `width`...use that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733955/what-are-the-differences-between-flex-grow-and-width

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish this: https://codepen.io/blimpage/pen/obWdgp

Comment: The value you're seeing is the full correct syntax for the `flex` rule: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex. There is nothing wrong with this. If your code is not working as you expect there is another issue which needs addressing

Comment: Since there is no `gallery-item` in the posted code, it is unclear how this is suppose to work, and therefore I decided to deleted my answer. In a comment at my answer you told the _flex-grow_ version doesn't work in Safari, so here is one, w/o the script, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VMXEbO ... so doesn't that work in Safari? ... And if you want to know _why_ the script based doesn't work, post a code snippet that includes the jQuery script and I'll have a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you want is equivalent to setting the flex-grow attribute:

[image]

so what you can do is just set the flex-grow attribute directly:

`$(this).css('flex', value + ' 1 0%');`

Comment: Why does setting `flex-grow` not give me the same result as this: https://codepen.io/blimpage/pen/obWdgp

Comment: ah apparently you need the flex-shrink and flex-basis properties to be set as well, so you can do `$(this).css('flex', value + ' 1 0%')` because flex-shrink and flex-basis default values are 1 and 0% respectively

Comment: Funnily enough that worked!   For some reason `$(this).css('flex', value + ' 1 0%')` works but setting flex-shrink and flex-basis in my css file then flex-grow via javascript does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Set it like this

```
 $(this).css("flex", value);
```

Comment: That gives me `style="flex: 1 1 1.7982456140350878px;"` when what i want is `style="flex: 1.7982456140350878;"` with no `px` and no `1 1`

Comment: the `:` in the question was a mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Add `px` after `value` variable

```
$('.gallery-item').each(function(){
  var value = $("img", this).width() / $("img", this).height();
  $(this).css("flex", value); // You had used `:` but should be `,` to separate two arguments.
});
```

Comment: I see my mistake but as the answer above that gives me `style="flex: 1 1 1.7982456140350878px;"` when what i want is `style="flex: 1.7982456140350878;"` with no `px` and no `1 1`