# Understanding the difference between the flex and flex-grow properties

Tags: css, flexbox

What is the difference in effect between setting `flex: 1;` and setting `flex-grow: 1;`? When I set the former in my code, the two columns I have display with equal width, while they do not do so when I set the latter.

This is strange, as I assumed that setting `flex: 1;` only affects the `flex-grow` property.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`flex` is a shorthand property of `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`.

In this case, `flex: 1` sets

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0` (in old spec drafts it was `flex-basis: 0%`)

If you only use `flex-grow: 1`, you will have

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: auto`

Then, the difference is that the flex base size will be 0 in the first case, so the flex items will have the same size after distributing free space.

In the second case each flex item will start with the size given by its content, and then will grow or shrink according to free space. Most probably the sizes will end up being different.

Comment: When setting flex: 1, each item will have the same size- How is that size determined? What is the benchmark?

Comment: @KevinWu The flex grow factor determines how a flex item will grow to cover available space relatively to others. If all have `flex-grow: 1`, they will grow the same.

Comment: @KevinWu, this related post may also help you understand `flex-grow`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34644807/3597276

Comment: For a graphical representation of what @Oriol wrote, check out this: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/images/rel-vs-abs-flex.svg