# flex vs flexGrow vs flexShrink vs flexBasis in React Native?

Tags: react-native, flexbox, flex-grow

I finally upgraded react native to 0.42 which includes the introduction of `flexGrow`, `flexShrink`, and  `flexBasis` and the change (or fix) of how `flex` is rendered.

I keep getting errors like:

> View was rendered with explicitly set width/height but with a 0 flexBasis. (This might be fixed by changing flex: to flexGrow:) View:

Can someone explain the difference between `flex: 1` vs `flexGrow: 1`.  If I apply one or the other to a View it seems to do different things but shouldn't it do the same?

Comment: It just apply CSS properties so you could have a look at [this question about difference between flex and flex-grow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35395691/understanding-the-difference-between-the-flex-and-flex-grow-properties)

Comment: Thanks.  The thing is, it's not the same as css, right?  In css flex: isn't just a number where in react native it is.  Do you know what the exceptions are when comparing react native flexbox to css flexbox?

Comment: Never used React Native, only React, and it generally doesn't do anything that magic with the style attribute, it merely assign the properties as CSS properties. But I haven't checked the code. I guess a good base for comparison would be to create a page in React Native and one using pure CSS, both generating the same markup and compare the results.

Answer (score 250, accepted):

Here's some test code to consider:

```
render() {
    return <View style={{flex: 1,backgroundColor: "cornflowerblue"}}>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: "chartreuse"}}><Text>Nothing (17px)</Text></View>

        <View style={{flex: 0, backgroundColor: "yellow"}}><Text>flex: 0 (17px)</Text></View>

        <View style={{flex: 0, flexBasis: 10, backgroundColor: "brown"}}><Text>flex: 0, flexBasis: 10 (10px)</Text></View>
        <View style={{flex: 0, flexGrow: 1, backgroundColor: "orange"}}><Text>flex: 0, flexGrow: 1 (97px)</Text></View>
        <View style={{flex: 0, flexShrink: 1, backgroundColor: "tan"}}><Text>flex: 0, flexShrink: 1 (17px)</Text></View>
        <View style={{flex: 0, flexGrow: 1, flexBasis: 10, backgroundColor: "purple"}}><Text>flex: 0, flexGrow: 1, flexBasis: 10 (90px)</Text></View>
        <View style={{flex: 0, flexShrink: 1, flexBasis: 10, backgroundColor: "gray"}}><Text>flex: 0, flexShrink: 1, flexBasis: 10 (10px with 7px hidden below the next element)</Text></View>

        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: "blue"}}><Text>flex: 1 (80px)</Text></View>

        <View style={{flex: 1, flexBasis: 10, backgroundColor: "cornsilk"}}><Text>flex: 1, flexBasis: 10 (90px)</Text></View>
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexGrow: 1, backgroundColor: "red"}}><Text>flex: 1, flexGrow: 1 (80px)</Text></View>
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexShrink: 1, backgroundColor: "green"}}><Text>flex: 1, flexShrink: 1 (80px)</Text></View>
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexGrow: 1, flexBasis: 10, backgroundColor: "aqua"}}><Text>flex: 1, flexGrow: 1, flexBasis: 10 (90px)</Text></View>
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexShrink: 1, flexBasis: 10, backgroundColor: "pink"}}><Text>flex: 1, flexShrink: 1, flexBasis: 10 (90px)</Text></View>
    </View>;
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the above code:

[image: Screenshot]

Added `width` and `height`:

```
render() {
    return <View style={{flex: 1,backgroundColor: "cornflowerblue"}}>
        <View style={{flex: 0, backgroundColor: "orange"}}><Text>flex: 0 (17px)</Text></View>
        <View style={{flex: 0, width: 700, height: 20, backgroundColor: "yellow"}}><Text>flex: 0, width: 700, height: 20 (20px)</Text></View>

        <View style={{flex: 0, flexBasis: 10, width: 700, height: 20, backgroundColor: "brown"}}><Text>flex: 0, flexBasis: 10, width: 700, height: 20 (10px with 7px hidden below the next element)</Text></View>
        <View style={{flex: 0, flexGrow: 1, width: 700, height: 20, backgroundColor: "orange"}}><Text>flex: 0, flexGrow: 1, width: 700, height: 20 (90px)</Text></View>
        <View style={{flex: 0, flexShrink: 1, width: 700, height: 20, backgroundColor: "tan"}}><Text>flex: 0, flexShrink: 1, width: 700, height: 20 (20px)</Text></View>
        <View style={{flex: 0, flexGrow: 1, flexBasis: 10, width: 700, height: 20, backgroundColor: "purple"}}><Text>flex: 0, flexGrow: 1, flexBasis: 10, width: 700, height: 20 (80px)</Text></View>
        <View style={{flex: 0, flexShrink: 1, flexBasis: 10, width: 700, height: 20, backgroundColor: "gray"}}><Text>flex: 0, flexShrink: 1, flexBasis: 10, width: 700, height: 20 (10px with 7px hidden below the next element)</Text></View>

        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: "orange"}}><Text>flex: 1 (70px)</Text></View>
        <View style={{flex: 1, width: 700, height: 20, backgroundColor: "blue"}}><Text>flex: 1, width: 700, height: 20 (70px)</Text></View>

        <View style={{flex: 1, flexBasis: 10, width: 700, height: 20, backgroundColor: "cornsilk"}}><Text>flex: 1, flexBasis: 10, width: 700, height: 20 (80px)</Text></View>
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexGrow: 1, width: 700, height: 20, backgroundColor: "red"}}><Text>flex: 1, flexGrow: 1, width: 700, height: 20 (70px)</Text></View>
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexShrink: 1, width: 700, height: 20, backgroundColor: "green"}}><Text>flex: 1, flexShrink: 1, width: 700, height: 20 (70px)</Text></View>
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexGrow: 1, flexBasis: 10, width: 700, height: 20, backgroundColor: "aqua"}}><Text>flex: 1, flexGrow: 1, flexBasis: 10, width: 700, height: 20 (80px)</Text></View>
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexShrink: 1, flexBasis: 10, width: 700, height: 20, backgroundColor: "pink"}}><Text>flex: 1, flexShrink: 1, flexBasis: 10, width: 700, height: 20 (80px)</Text></View>
    </View>;
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the above code:

[image: Screenshot 2]

### `flex: 0` (default)

- **`flex: 0`**

  - Element takes the size of contents.  According to the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#flexgrow) it should be sized by setting `width` and `height` props but it seems to fit to contents if those aren't set.
- **`flex: 0, flexBasis: {{px}}`**

  - Element takes the size given by `flexBasis`
- **`flex: 0, flexGrow: 1`**

  - With `flex: 0` and `flexGrow: 1`; it's the same as adding the size of the contents (in the example above it's a ) to the size of an element that's set to `flex: 1`. It's similar to `flex: 1, flexBasis: 10` except instead of adding a number of pixels you're adding the size of the content.
- **`flex: 0, flexShrink: 1`**

  - With `flex: 0` and `flexShrink: 1`, the element seems to take the size of the content, in other words it's the same as just `flex: 0`. I'll bet there are situations where it would be bigger than the content but I haven't see that yet.
- **`flex: 0, flexGrow: 1, flexBasis: {{px}}`**

  - This is the same as `flex: 0, flexGrow: 1` except instead of adding the content size to a `flex: 1` element it adds the given number of pixels.
- **`flex: 0, flexShrink: 1, flexBasis: {{px}}`**

  - This is the same as `flex: 0, flexBasis: {{px}}`.
- **`flex: 0, height: {{px}}`**

  - With `flex: 0`, `height` is treated just like `flexBasis`.  If there is both a `height` and `flexBasis` are set, `height` is ignored.

### `flex: 1`

- **`flex: 1`**

  - Element takes available space. See [Layout Props documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#flexgrow) for more details
- **`flex: 1, flexBasis: {{px}}`**

  - With `flex: 1` and `flexBasis: {{px}}`; the value of `flexBasis` is added to the element's size. In other words, it's like taking a `flex: 1` element and adding on the number of pixels set by `flexBasis`. So if a `flex: 1` element is 50px, and you add `flexBasis: 20` the element will now be 70px.
- **`flex: 1, flexGrow: 1`**

  - ignored
- **`flex: 1, flexShrink: 1`**

  - ignored
- **`flex: 1, flexGrow: 1, flexBasis: {{px}}`**

  - This is the same as `flex: 1, flexBasis: {{px}}` since `flexGrow` is ignored.
- **`flex: 1, flexShrink: 1, flexBasis: {{px}}`**

  - This is the same as `flex: 1, flexBasis: {{px}}` since `flexShrink` is ignored.
- **`flex: 1, height: {{px}}`**

  - With `flex: 1`, `height` is ignored.  Use `flexBasis` instead.

### Here are my observations:

- **Trouble Shooting Tip:** Make sure the parent view(s) are giving the children room to grow/shrink.  Notice the `flex: 1` on the parent view, without it, all the children don't display as you'd expect.
- **Trouble Shooting Tip:** Don't use `Hot Reloading` when testing these values, it can display elements incorrectly after it's reloaded a few times.  I recommend enabling `Live Reload` or using <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> (a lot).
- The default flex value is `flex: 0`.  If you don't add a flex style value it defaults to 0.
- **Trouble Shooting Tip:** if you're tryign to figure out why something isn't displaying like you think it should, start with the (most) parent element and make sure it's giving enough space to it's children to do what they need to do.  In other words, try setting it to flex:1 and see if that helps, then go to the next child and repeat.
- It seems like `width` is always considered with `flexDirection: "column"` no matter the other flex props.  The same applies for `height` with `flexDirection: "row"`.
- After running these test, in general I would use `flexBasis` over `height` since `flexBasis` trumps `height`.

Comment: Great overview! One thing I've noticed is that changing `flexBasis` on the fly doesn't fly well with react-native

Comment: Maybe I'm reading it wrong but flex:1 and flexGrow:1 is not the same as flex: 1 (flexGrow is not ignored in any sense, those two give different results.