# Picker placement is wrong on react-native view

Tags: ios, react-native, picker

I'm following this [Udemy react-native course](https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-react-native-and-redux-course/learn/v4/overview) and in one of the examples he uses a picker to select data in the screen. Back when he tried it it seems like it was working but now I get a weird result when I try to render it.

If I follow his code exactly the picker shows after all the other items, after making some changes I get it to show kind of at the right place but it is now squished, which is still not correct:

[image: bad pickler]

I am definitely doing something wrong here in terms of how to render it, here's the code ([full example on github](https://github.com/mauricio/manager/blob/master/src/components/EmployeeCreate.js)):

```
import React from 'react';
import {Picker, Text, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Card, CardSection, Input, Button} from "./common";
import {employeeUpdate} from "../actions";

class EmployeeCreate extends React.Component {

  updateEmployee(name, value) {
    this.props.employeeUpdate({prop: name, value: value})
  }

  renderPickerItems() {
    return ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']
      .map((item) => <Picker.Item key={item} label={item} value={item}/>);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Card>

        <CardSection>
          <Input
            label="Name"
            placeholder="Your Name"
            value={this.props.name}
            onChangeText={this.updateEmployee.bind(this, 'name')}
          />
        </CardSection>

        <CardSection>
          <Input
            label="Phone"
            placeholder="555-555-5555"
            keyboardType="phone-pad"
            value={this.props.phone}
            onChangeText={this.updateEmployee.bind(this, 'phone')}
          />
        </CardSection>

        <CardSection style={{flex: 1}}>
          <View style={styles.shiftContainerStyle}>
            <Text style={styles.pickerTextStyle}>Shift</Text>
            <Picker
              style={styles.pickerStyle}
              selectedValue={this.props.shift}
              onValueChange={this.updateEmployee.bind(this, 'shift')}
            >
              {this.renderPickerItems()}
            </Picker>
          </View>
        </CardSection>

        <CardSection>
          <Button>
            Create
          </Button>
        </CardSection>

      </Card>
    );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  pickerTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    lineHeight: 23,
    flex: 1,
  },
  pickerStyle: {
    flex: 2,
  },
  shiftContainerStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }
});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const {name, phone, shift} = state.employeeForm;

  return {
    name,
    phone,
    shift,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {employeeUpdate})(EmployeeCreate);
```

Any idea what I could do to render this correctly?

Comment: What is it supposed to look like? If you remove the `style={{flex: 1}}` from that third `CardSection`, it'll render as I would expect it to render. But without access to the course, I have nothing to compare it against.

Comment: I'd expect to render just like the inputs, by the right of the shift label with the button below them as a block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove `style={{flex: 1}}` from this line in your code:

```
<CardSection style={{flex: 1}}>
```

The reason being that your parent container, `Card`, doesn't have any `flex` or `width/height` values defined. If `flex` is left undefined, [the default is `flex: 0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143258/flex-vs-flexgrow-vs-flexshrink-vs-flexbasis-in-react-native). If you look at the docs for [`flex`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#flex), you'll see that:

> When `flex` is 0, the component is sized according to `width` and `height` and it is inflexible.

Combine that with having no `width/height` defined and you get this behavior on rendering your `CardSection`s:

- The three `CardSection`s (input, input, button) will take up the default `width` and `height` based on their children. That is the default styling for the `Input`s and `Button`.
- The `CardSection` with `style={{flex: 1}}` will calculate its `width` and `height` based on the remaining space taken up by the parent container(s) per the definition of `flex: 1`:

> When `flex` is a positive number, it makes the component flexible and it will be sized proportional to its `flex` value. So a component with `flex` set to 2 will take twice the space as a component with `flex` set to 1.

- The parent container, `Card`, in this case has no extra space left. So what happens is that this `CardSection` ends up with 0 `height`. Hence the strange overflow rendering you're seeing.

Once you remove `style={{flex: 1}}`, the `width` and `height` of the `CardSection` will be defined by it's child components which, like `Input` and `Button`, do have a styles and default styles.

Whether or not this is correct behavior per the [Yoga](https://yogalayout.com) spec (Yoga is what React Native uses for layout) is up for [debate](https://github.com/facebook/yoga/issues/701) and has [tripped up](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3929) others before. Definitely look over that [first StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143258/flex-vs-flexgrow-vs-flexshrink-vs-flexbasis-in-react-native) I linked to as it has far more detail and explanation on gotchas than any of the documentation on React Native wrt `flex`.

Comment: Awesome stuff! Thanks for the thorough answer!