# Stretch child to 100% width and height without changing the child's rules

Tags: css, flexbox

When parent is `display: flex;`, is there a way to force it's children to stretch itself to 100% of the parent's width and height, without accessing the children's props?

i've found `align-items: stretch;` for vertical stretching, but can't find something for the horizontal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*"I've found align-items: stretch; for vertical stretching, but can't find something for the horizontal"*

I guess you're searching for `justify-content` property, but it doesn't have `stretch` rule, it only can accept the following rules: `justify-content: flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around | space-evenly;`

**But**

You can specify `flex-grow: 1` for child element and it will fill all available space of the parent.

Here is the example (I have added paddings to parent element just for example, so you can see the difference between parent and child):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: orangered;
  padding: 8px;
}

.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: forestgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
<div>
```

Comment: `flex: 1;` is **not** equal to `flex-grow: 1`

Comment: That describe the _syntax_ for `flex` shorthand and does not say they are equal. The W3C specs. is the [proper docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common), and this answer explains it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35395869/2827823

Answer (score 5):

> is there a way to force it's children to stretch itself to 100% of the
>   parent's width and height, without accessing the children's props?

No, as for an i.e. flex *row* item (the default), its default width is `auto`, which make it depend/size by its content, and for it to stretch horizontal (fill the remaining space), it needs `flex-grow: 1`.

The same goes for flex *column* item, where the `flex-grow: 1` will make it fill the parent's height.

---

> i've found `align-items: stretch;` for vertical stretching, but can't
>   find something for the horizontal

When it comes to `align-items` and its default `stretch`, it affect the cross axis, and will for i.e a flex *row* item, stretch it to fill its parent's height, and for a flex *column* item it is the other way around, where it fill its parent's width.

There is no property for the main axis that does the same, as that is what the `flex` property is for, here as shorthand `flex: <flex-grow> <flex-shrink> <flex-basis>`, and since one might want different behavior for different items, it is set on the flex item (what you call the *child*)

---

Here is a flex *row* samples using `flex-grow: 1`

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```