# How to prevent a flex box from growing with content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the code and jsfiddle below, flexbox proportions changes with content. I am feeling I do not understand the real purpose of flexbox here. If we are giving `flex-grow` properties for the proportions we desire, why do the boxes grow with content?

Notice when `dataDiv` has new span content in it, proportions are broken with the content. You can observe how it is the expected proportions when you delete the `span` inside `dataDiv`. Why does this occur?

https://jsfiddle.net/4shaz5oy/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}
.mapBox {
  flex: 2;
  background-color: red;
}
.controlBox {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: green;
}
.controlPanel {
  flex: 1;
  max-height: 33%;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.dataPanel {
  flex: 2;
  max-height: 66%;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mapBox"></div>
  <div class="controlBox">
    <div class="controlPanel">
      <div class="buttonDiv"></div>
      <div class="buttonDiv"></div>
      <div class="buttonDiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dataPanel">
      <div class="dataDiv">
        <span>yoyoyoyasdasdadsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdadada</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [flex-grow not sizing flex items as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644807/flex-grow-not-sizing-flex-items-as-expected)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `flex-grow` defines how the remaining space should be distributed amongst the flex items, not the items themselves.

For their size you use `flex-basis`

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    height: 100vh;
}

.mapBox {
    flex: 2;
    flex-basis: 66%;
    background-color: red;
}

.controlBox {
    flex: 1;
    flex-basis: 33%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    background-color:green;
}

.controlPanel {
    flex: 1;
    max-height: 33%;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.dataPanel {
    flex: 2;
    max-height: 66%;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mapBox">

  </div>

  <div class="controlBox">
    <div class="controlPanel">
      <div class="buttonDiv">

      </div>
      <div class="buttonDiv">

      </div>
      <div class="buttonDiv">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dataPanel">
      <div class="dataDiv">
        <span>yoyoyoy as da sd ad sa da sd as da sd as da sd as da sd ad ada</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Based on comments, here is a simplified sample of how to keep size

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
}
.flex, .left, .right {
  display: flex;
}
.left, .right {
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.left {
  background: red;
  flex-basis: 66.66%;
}
.right {
  flex-basis: 33.33%;
}
.item1 {
  background: yellow;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 33.33vh;
}
.item2 {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="left">
    Bla 0 Bla 0 Bla 0 Bla 0 Bla 0 Bla 0 Bla 0 Bla 0 Bla 0 Bla 0 Bla 0 Bla 0 Bla 0 Bla 0 Bla 0 Bla 0 Bla 0 Bla 0 Bla 0 Bla 0 <br>
    Bla 0<br>
    Bla 0<br>
    Bla 0<br>
    Bla 0<br>

  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="item1">
      Bla 1 Bla 1 Bla 1 Bla 1 Bla 1 Bla 1 Bla 1 Bla 1 Bla 1 Bla 1 Bla 1 Bla 1 Bla 1 Bla 1 Bla 1 <br>
      Bla 1<br>
      Bla 1<br>
      Bla 1<br>
      Bla 1<br>

      Bla 1<br>
      Bla 1<br>
      Bla 1<br>
      Bla 1<br>
      Bla 1<br>

    </div>
    <div class="item2">
      Bla 2 Bla 2 Bla 2 Bla 2 Bla 2 Bla 2 Bla 2 Bla 2 Bla 2 Bla 2 Bla 2 Bla 2 Bla 2 Bla 2 Bla 2 <br>
      Bla 2<br>
      Bla 2<br>
      Bla 2<br>
      Bla 2<br>

      Bla 2<br>
      Bla 2<br>
      Bla 2<br>
      Bla 2<br>
      Bla 2<br>

      Bla 2<br>
      Bla 2<br>
      Bla 2<br>
      Bla 2<br>
      Bla 2<br>

    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Basis solves the problem with horizontal growing, which I knew it would. However at the end, when you add content into dataDiv, heights of conrolPanel and dataPanel still changes. I guess it is what flex is for and there is no way to change that. Probably just my view on it. If I want fixed height maybe I should absolute positioning instead of flex for controlBox.

Comment: @OzumSafa `flex` has some flaws, which I solved many times with an absolute positioned inner div, set to `overflow: auto`. This way it doesn't grow vertical but rather start to scroll.

Comment: @OzumSafa Updated my answer with a new 2:nd sample.

Comment: Also works in safari. It is an interesting solution, however somewhat a hack. I will mark it as answered. Thanks.

Comment: @OzumSafa Thanks, and I just updated ... works across browsers now, less hacky :)

Answer (score 7):

It looks like everything works as expected, the problem is there is no space among `yoyoyoyasdasdadsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdadada` that focus the box to grow.

If you set `.dataPanel {word-break: break-all;}` you'll see the differences.