# How to prevent content from re-sizing a flex item?

Tags: html, css, charts, flexbox

I'm using CSS flexbox to build a scalable, responsive grid. When applying a Google chart to one of the flexbox items, the item changes size ever so slightly. It's enough to throw the grid out of alignment. I put together the following images to help illustrate the issue.

Flexbox grid before applying Google chart to item 6:

[image: Flexbox Layout - Before Google Chart]

Flexbox grid after applying Google chart to item 6:

[image: Flexbox Layout - After Google Chart]

The Flexbox grid loads faster than the Google chart, so the grid originally loads correctly. However when the chart loads, item 6 expands slightly, causing image 2 above.

The middle column flex container and item 6 div are setup in css as follows:

```
#middlecolumn {
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    margin: 0.25%;
}

#item6_div {
    flex: 3;
    margin-top: 0.8vh;
}
```

Note that items 5 and 7 are setup the same way in css, with `flex` values of `1`. I.e. item 6 is 3 times the height of items 5 and 7. As such, when item 6 resizes, the 3:1 ratio is maintained.

Is there something I'm missing in css to prevent the Google chart from resizing its flexbox container item?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When you tell a flex item to `flex: 3` (Item 6) or `flex: 1` (Items 5 & 7), here's how that shorthand property breaks down:

```
flex: ?  =  <flex-grow>, <flex-shrink>, <flex-basis>

flex: 3 =  flex-grow: 3, flex-shrink: 1, flex-basis: 0

flex: 1 =  flex-grow: 1, flex-shrink: 1, flex-basis: 0
```

In both cases, the `flex-shrink` factor is 1, meaning the flex item is allowed to shrink proportionally.

To prevent the flex items from shrinking, which may be causing the misalignment, I would change the `flex-shrink` to 0.

Instead of `flex: 3` and `flex: 1` try:

```
flex: 3 0 0;
flex: 1 0 0;
```

More details in the flexbox spec: [7.1.1. Basic Values of `flex`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/CR-css-flexbox-1-20160301/#flex-common)

---

But you may have another problem. You wrote:

> Note that items 5 and 7 are setup the same way in css, with `flex` values of `1`. I.e. item 6 is 3 times the height of items 5 and 7. As such, when item 6 resizes, the 3:1 ratio is maintained.

This is not how the `flex-grow` property works.

By applying `flex-grow: 3` to a flex item you are telling it to consume three times more available space than flex items with `flex-grow: 1`. This does not necessarily mean Item 6 will be three times the size of Items 5 and 7.

Learn more about how `flex-grow` works here: **[flex-grow not sizing flex items as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34644807/3597276)**

As an alternative sizing method, you may want to use the `flex-basis` property. Try `flex: 0 0 60%` on Item 6, and `flex: 0 0 20%` on Items 5 and 7.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution could be used to keep a column contain all the available space: use the grow and shrink to 0 on other columns, and flex-grow=1 to the full width column, eg ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/eYKYRbe)):

```js
function update() {
  var text =
    "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.";
  document.querySelector(".three").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```css
.container > div:not(.three) {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.one { width: 10%; }    
.two { width: 200px; }    

.three { flex-grow: 1; }

.four { width: 200px; }    
.five { width: 10%; }

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  background: tomato;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.container > div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: green;
}

.three { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one"> one </div>
  <div class="two"> two <br />
    <button onclick="update()">update</button>
  </div>
  <div class="three"> three </div>
  <div class="four"> four </div>
  <div class="five"> five </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's not the best solution but it works for me:

for example, if you have a line of four items that should spread evenly on your entire screen.

add in CSS for each of them:

```
min-width: 20vw;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply this css to the part you want to stretch:

```
flex: 1
```