# How to make div (button) 100% instead of 50% when no other buttons

Tags: html, css

I need that when there is only one button it will be 100% width:

css based answer if it's possible
[image: here is the div's look]

Comment: Could you make a Fiddle for that?

Comment: Give the button width: 100vw;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make use of the `:only-of-type` selector to override the `width` property like in the below snippet.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

/* if button is input tag */
input[type='button'] {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
input[type='button']:only-of-type {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

/* if button is button tag */
button {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
button:only-of-type {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h4>For Buttons using input tag</h4>
<div class='container'>
  <input type='button' value='Button 1' />
  <input type='button' value='Button 2' />
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <input type='button' value='Button 1' />
</div>

<h4>For Buttons using buton tag</h4>

<div class='container'>
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <button>Button 1</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed a great answer However I do think its more suits you to use flexbox or display-table cell since you'll can possibly have more than 2 buttons no ?
@alonblack

Comment: @Baldráni: Question states original state is button width is 50%. I assume that means there is no more than 2. Moreover, `:only-of-type` has better browser support than flexbox.

Answer (score 3):

You can use flexbox to solve this problem:

```css
.buttons {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items:stretch;
}
.btn {
  border:1px solid #000;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="btn">Test</div>
  <div class="btn">Test</div>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="btn">Test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try display: table;  by using it if you have 3 link it will take 33.33% width automatically

```css
.btn-box{
  margin: 30px 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout=fixed;
  /* Presentation purpose */
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:30px
  }
.btn-box div{
  background: #000;
  height: 30px;
  display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="btn-box">
    <div>
       Box1
    </div>
    <div>
       Box2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-box">
    <div>
       Only box
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:flex;` in the container and `flex-grow:2;` in the children elements.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: thin solid #dddddd;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  display:flex;
}
.btn {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #999999;
  border: thin solid #666666;
  float: left;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  flex-grow: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn">
    Ok
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
    Cancel
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="btn">
    Cancel
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `flex-grow: 1` or `flex: 1` would do the same thing.

Comment: Didn't know that! Thanks! So `flex` property is just a shorthand for `flex-grow` or are there any difference in use?

Comment: The `flex` property is shorthand for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, `flex-basis`. For a deeper understanding of `flex-grow` see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34644807/3597276

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use :only-child 
The :only-child selector matches every element that is the only child of its parent.

Sample HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <button type="button" class="left">Button1</button>
  <button type="button" class="right">Button2</button>
</div>
```

Required CSS:

```
.left:only-child {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 50px;
}
.left {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 50px;
}
.right {
    width: 50%;
    background-color:#ddd;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}
```