# aligning columns in two rows of flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two rows: one with 4 buttons and one with 3 buttons.

I want the second row's first column to match with the first row's second column in *flexbox*.

Here is my code, any help is appreciated.

```
<div> 
  <div style="display: flex"> 
    <button style="flex: 1"> A </button> 
    <button style="flex: 1"> B </button>
    <button style="flex: 1"> C </button> 
    <button style="flex: 1"> D </button> 
  </div> 
  <div style="display: flex"> 
    <button style="flex: 2"> B </button>
    <button style="flex: 1"> C </button> 
    <button style="flex: 1"> D </button> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Did you want the 2nd row button to be that big? If so, are the other 2 buttons going to shrink or wrap to a third row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using an invisible flex item in the second row.

For more accurate sizing, use the `flex-basis` property (similar to `width`, in this case).

With `flex-grow`, you'll have a harder time aligning the columns in both rows. `flex-grow` is more concerned with the distribution of free space than precise sizing of flex items. ([More details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644807/flex-grow-not-sizing-flex-items-as-expected).)

```html
<div>
  <div style="display: flex">
    <button style="flex: 1 1 25%">A</button>
    <button style="flex: 1 1 25%">B</button>
    <button style="flex: 1 1 25%">C</button>
    <button style="flex: 1 1 25%">D</button>
  </div>
  <div style="display: flex">
    <button style="flex: 1 1 25%; visibility: hidden;">A</button>
    <button style="flex: 1 1 50%">B</button>
    <button style="flex: 1 1 12.5%">C</button>
    <button style="flex: 1 1 12.5%">D</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f2048ty1/)

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm afraid this is going to be downvoted, but I read the arguments for/against using tables for layout. I came here after reading those arguments... one of which is "less code", however in this case it looks like possibly more code which is also more complicated to understand.

I also struggled to get columns aligned across multiple rows.

I read the accepted answer, looked at the other responses, then went back, removed my div's and used a table.

There are situations where a table is just plain old easier.

Comment: when alignment is needed on desktop but mobile should be supported, you can consider using different markup for desktop and mobile

Answer (score 1):

May not be the right solution, but a suggestion/work around !!

**Suggestion 1:**

```html
<div>
  <div style="display: flex">
    <button style="flex: 1">A</button>
    <button style="flex: 1">B</button>
    <button style="flex: 1">C</button>
    <button style="flex: 1">D</button>
  </div>
  <div style="display: flex">
    <button style="flex: 1;visibility: hidden">B</button>
    <button style="flex: 1">B</button>
    <button style="flex: 1">C</button>
    <button style="flex: 1">D</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Suggestion 2:**

```html
<div>
  <div style="display: flex">
    <button style="flex: 1">A</button>
    <button style="flex: 1">B</button>
    <button style="flex: 1">C</button>
    <button style="flex: 1">D</button>
  </div>
  <div style="display: flex">
    <button style="flex: 1; margin-left: 25%">B</button> <!-- 25% = 100/(No. of buttons in previous row) -->
    <button style="flex: 1">C</button>
    <button style="flex: 1">D</button>
  </div>
</div>
```