# Understanding flex-grow

Tags: html, css, flexbox, flex-grow

I have 3 divs and if I give `flex: 0.5` to first two divs, the last div should move to the next line if I have given `flex-wrap: wrap`. Please correct if I am wrong.

Following is my html / css:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.child-1 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 0.5;
}
.child-2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 0.5;
}
.child-3 {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1">LOREN IPSUM LOREN IPSUM</div>
  <div class="child-2">LOREN IPSUMLOREN IPSUMLOREN IPSUM</div>
  <div class="child-3">LOREN IPSUMLOREN IPSUM</div>
</div>
```

Please check [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u7fb0of4/) for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you want `flex: 50%`, which is not the same as `flex: 0.5`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `flex-grow` property is designed to distribute free space in the container among flex items.

It is *not* intended for directly or precisely sizing flex items.

*From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex-grow):*

> `flex-grow` ... determines how much the flex item will grow relative
>   to the rest of the flex items in the flex container when positive free
>   space is distributed.

Hence, `flex-grow` will not force items to wrap. Here's your example with `flex-grow: 1000`: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u7fb0of4/1/)

To define a length of a flex item use `width`, `height` or `flex-basis`.

---

### Explaining `flex-grow: 0.5`

When you apply `flex:0.5`, you're using the `flex` shorthand property to say this:

- `flex-grow: 0.5`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0`

The `flex-grow` component represents a proportion. In this case, it's telling flex items to consume *half of the available space in the container relative to the `flex-grow` factor of its siblings*.

So, for instance, if the container were `width: 600px` and the total width of the three divs was 450px, this would leave 150px in free space ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u7fb0of4/2/)).

If each item had `flex-grow: 1`, then each item would consume 50px of the extra space, and each item would compute to `width: 200px` ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u7fb0of4/3/)).

But in your code, two items have `flex-grow: 0.5`, and the last item has `flex-grow: 0`, so here's how it breaks down:

> - div#1 will get 75px (half of the available space)
> - div#2 will get 75px (half of the available space)
> - div#3 will get 0 (because its `flex-grow` is 0)

These are the computed values now:

> - div#1 = `width: 225px`
> - div#2 = `width: 225px`
> - div#3 = `width: 150px`

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u7fb0of4/4/)

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 600px;
}

.parent > div {
  flex-basis: 150px;
}

.child-1 {
  flex: 0.5;
  background-color: green;
}

.child-2 {
  flex: 0.5;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.child-3 {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1">LOREN IPSUM LOREN IPSUM</div>
  <div class="child-2">LOREN IPSUMLOREN IPSUMLOREN IPSUM</div>
  <div class="child-3"> LOREN IPSUMLOREN IPSUM</div>
</div>
```

*NOTE: The truth of the matter is, because divs #1 and #2 have the same `flex-grow` factor, and div #3 has a factor of 0, the value is irrelevant. You could use any number to replace 0.5. As long as it's the same in both divs, the items will compute to 225px, because the proportions will be the same.*

More information:

- [flex-grow not sizing flex items as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34644807/3597276)
- [How to get flexbox to include padding in calculations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37785345/3597276)
- [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

Flex = 0.5 means, you have flex-grow = 0.5, flex-shrink = 1 and flex-basis = 0
you are allocating the available space to flex items.

Let's just say, you have a container (Assuming div element) of width: 100vw with two flexible items(div elements) of each 40vw in it. So the total width consumed by your two div elements will be equals to 80vw and the left over available space would be 20vw. Now, You have set the flex = 0.5 for each of the two div elements. so, Each div element will grow up by 20vw/2 = 10vw in order to fully occupy the free space of the container.

Consider one more scenario with 3 div elements, div1 of width = 30vw, div2 of width = 10vw and div3 of width = 25vw.
Total width consumed by 3 div elements = 30 + 10 + 25 = 65vw.
Total available space = 100 - 65 = 35vw.

Now, Each div element is set to flex = 0.3, so each will grow up by 35/3 =~ 11.66vw