# How to get flexbox to include padding in calculations?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Below are two rows.

- **First row** is two items at `flex 1` and one at `flex 2`.
- **Second Row** is two items at `flex 1`.

According to the spec **1A + 1B = 2A**

But when **padding** is included in the calculation the sum is incorrect as you can see in the example below.

---

**QUESTION**

How to get flex box to include padding into its calculation so the boxes in the example line up correctly?

```css
.Row{
  display:flex;
}
.Item{
  display:flex;
  flex:1;
  flex-direction:column;
  padding:0 10px 10px 0;
}
.Item > div{
  background:#7ae;
}
.Flx2{
  flex:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="Row">
  <div class="Item">
    <div>1A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Item">
    <div>1B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Item Flx2">
    <div>1C</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Row">
  <div class="Item">
    <div>2A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Item">
    <div>2B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 127, accepted):

The solution:

Set `margin` on the child element instead of `padding` on your `flex` item.

```css
.Row{
  display:flex;
}
.Item{
  display:flex;
  flex:1;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.Item > div{
  background:#7ae;
  margin:0 10px 10px 0;
}
.Flx2{
  flex:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="Row">
  <div class="Item">
    <div>1A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Item">
    <div>1B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Item Flx2">
    <div>1C</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Row">
  <div class="Item">
    <div>2A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Item">
    <div>2B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

The problem:

The calculation is done without `padding`. So; adding `padding` to the `flex` element is not giving you your expected width by the 
[spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/).

[The specific article](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#line-sizing)

> For example, the available space to a flex item in a floated auto-sized flex container is:
>
> - the width of the flex container’s containing block minus the flex container’s margin, border, and padding in the horizontal dimension
> - infinite in the vertical dimension

Why is the padding not calculated? That's what the spec wants.

> *Determine the available `main` and `cross` space for the `flex` items*. For each dimension, if that dimension of the `flex container`’s content box is a definite size, use that; if that dimension of the `flex container` is being sized under a `min` or `max-content` constraint, the available space in that dimension is that constraint; otherwise, **subtract the flex container’s margin, border, and padding from the space available to the flex container in that dimension and use that value**. *This might result in an infinite value.*

If you subtract the `padding` and `margin` from the element's size, you get:

**1A + 1B = 2A**

However, after you did that, the padding was added to the element. The more elements, the more padding. That's not being calculated in the width, causing your statement to be false.

Comment: This not only solved my problem but was very helpful understanding flex also. Thank you.

Comment: the problem with using margin instead of padding is that when you hover on the margin section, it won't count as you hovering on that element.

Comment: It also doesn't help when you need the padding for borders.  I was hoping setting `box-sizing: border box;` would help but no such luck...

Comment: It's not really clear: The spec section you highlighted says: **"...subtract the flex container's margin, border and padding from the space available..."** But the padding isn't on the flex container. It's on the flex items. (The nested flex container isn't relevant to the problem.) So I'm not sure those excerpts apply.

Comment: using margin on children instantly adds scollbars even if there's no content in the child

Comment: @johntrepreneur Not in my example, if you can ask a new question with your issue maybe we can find out why.

Comment: how is it possible that they screwed this up so badly? I think I'm going back to html tables for layout, clearly that algorithm was written by a different generation of programmers.

Answer (score 7):

> How to get flexbox to include padding in calculations?

In your code, padding *is* included in the calculations.

> According to the spec **1A + 1B = 2A**

I don't believe this is correct. Maybe provide a link reference for an explanation.

---

### The  `flex-grow` property

When you apply `flex: 1` to an element, you are using the `flex` shorthand property to say this:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0`

`flex-grow` tells a flex item to consume the free space in the container.

Here is your code:

```
.Item {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

In the first row, `padding-right: 10px` is applied to **three** flex items.

In the second row, `padding-right: 10px` is applied to **two** flex items.

Hence, in the first row there is 10px less free space to distribute. This breaks the grid's alignment.

For distributing space (e.g., you want an element to take the remaining height or width of a container), use `flex-grow`.

For precise sizing of a flex item use `flex-basis`, `width` or `height`.

Here's some more info:

- [flex-grow not sizing flex items as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34644807/3597276)
- [How exactly does flex-grow work with flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37617872/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

You can add wrapper element inside your flex child. Giving padding to that element won't affect root flex element's width/height.

```html
<div style='display: flex;'>
  <div>
    <div style='padding: 10px;'>
      <-- your other elements  -->
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code to help beginner to reproduce this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow the accepted answer. The nested flex container doesn't seem to be relevant to the problem. If you run the example without `display: flex;` on `.Item`, the problem persists.

The problem here seems to be that `flex-grow` only calculates the available space that it can take after factoring in the cumulative horizontal padding.

Let's assume the top level flex container is 300px wide.

**1st row's available space**: 300px - 30px padding = 270px

The flex items in this row have `flex-grow`s of 1, 1, and 2, for a total of 4 units. 270 / 4 = 67.5px. The content boxes of 1A and 1B are thus 67.5px each, the content box of 1C is 135px.

**2nd row's available space**: 300px - 20px padding = 280px

We have `flex-grow`s of 1 for both 2A and 2B in this row. 280 / 2 = 140px.

So 1A and 1B would have a content box of 67.5px + 10px horizontal padding, making their total width 77.5px each.

2A would have a content box of 140px + 10px horizontal padding, making its total width 150px.

77.5px + 77.5px ≠ 150px. In other words, 1A + 1B ≠ 2A, and that's why they aren't lining up.

The accepted answer does solve the problem, but CSS grid has become well supported since that answer was submitted, and is the more idiomatic approach nowadays for this problem.

```css
.Row{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}

.Item:nth-child(n + 3) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.Item > div{
  background:#7ae;
}
```

```html
<div class="Row">
  <div class="Item">
    <div>1A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Item">
    <div>1B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Item">
    <div>1C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Item">
    <div>2A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Item">
    <div>2B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, when using flexbox, the padding property is not included in the calculation of the element's width or height. To include the padding in the calculation, you can set the box-sizing property to border-box.

```css
.Row{
  display:flex;
}
.Item{
  display:flex;
  flex:1;
  flex-direction:column;
  padding:0 10px 10px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box; // Add this line
}
.Item > div{
  background:#7ae;
}
.Flx2{
  flex:2;
}
```

Comment: Did you check this, or is it just a guess? This is not accurate!

Comment: This is working right now on a project that I was working on literally yesterday. So yes. I've checked it. @DreamTeK

Answer (score -3):

You can use floated pseudo block elements instead of padding, like this:
(In this case 30px right padding)

```css
.Item:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of extra mark up for each element. I don't think this is a good solution.