# Bootstrap 4 Card Flex Width is not working correctly on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have a problem trying to make a webpage with bootstrap 4 and flex. I am using Bootstrap cards with certain width. I see that this works fine in Google Chrome and Opera but appears to not work in Firefox.
Here is my code:

```
    <div class="row auxAltura2">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header colorPlataforma">
                Tags
            </div>
            <div id="moduloTags" class="card-body">
                ...

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

And now here is my css:

```
   .auxAltura2{height:250px}
    .card-header{
        display: flex;
        flex: 1 0 30px;
        align-items: center;
        font-size:17px;
    }
```

Image card on firefox:

[image]

And this is image from card on Opera:

[image]

You can see the difference between the 2 browsers. Is a bug? 
Glad if you can help me. Thanks for all.

Comment: use bootstrap 4 flex `<div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-center  colorPlataforma">` instead use your css:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: see support flex in firefox:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Comment: @לבנימלכה That doesnt work for me. If you see [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) you can see that width in  Firefox is different than Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is `padding` on flex element, which is added extra to your `30px` `.card-header` height.

You should set the top and bottom padding of `.card-header` to 0;

See this SO question for more details:
[How to get flexbox to include padding in calculations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785345/how-to-get-flexbox-to-include-padding-in-calculations)

Comment: My sorry, now I understand you. I put padding-top and bottom to 0 and now it works. Nice answer, thanks.