# responsive drop down menu not drop down in media screen

Tags: html

The responsive drop down menu work well here:

https://klia2.co/include/header.htm

but when insert to content page as below, the drop down menu not drop down when view in media screen.

https://klia2.co/index2.htm

compared the 2 links to understand the actual scenario.

Notice that the alignment of logo header and menu in content page also not tally.

Kindly assist to rectify the issue and all suggestion are most welcome and appreciated.

```
HTML PAGE - index2.htm

<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<div class="content">
<br>
   <br>
   ** content **  
 <br>
<br>

<div id="footer"></div>

 </div>

</body>

HTML PAGE - header.htm

<body>

 <div class="content">
 
          
    <header id="logo"></header>


    <div class="navbar" id="nav">
      <a href="https://klia2.co" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="../facilities/index.htm">Facilities</a>
      <a href="../airlines/index.htm">Airlines Offices</a>
      <form class="search-box">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
    <button type="submit" class="search-icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    
  </form>
    
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>  
</div>
</div>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("nav");
      
      console.log(barIcon)
      if (x.className === "navbar") {
        x.className += " responsive";
        var barIcon = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-bars')[0];
        barIcon.classList.add("fa-times");
        barIcon.classList.remove("fa-bars");
      } else {
        var closeIcon = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-times')[0];
        closeIcon.classList.remove("fa-times");
closeIcon.classList.add("fa-bars");
        x.className = "navbar";
      }
    }  
</script>    

</body>


CSS CODE - style1.css




/* CSS Reset */

body {font-family:Arial;
}

.content {
  max-width: 1040px;
  margin: auto;

}





/*--------------------------logo---------------------------------*/




#logo {
    background: transparent url("images/airlineshq-logo.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    width: 1040px;
    height: 150px;
        border: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    
     }

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
#logo {
width: 100%;

}
}

/*--------------------------menu---------------------------------*/


.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #0000ff;
      
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  height:18px;
     

}
.active {
  background-color: #0033CC;
  color: white;
  

}
.navbar .icon {
  display: none;
  

}
.navbar a:hover, input:hover {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  color: black;
}
/* CSS for search box */
.navbar .search-box {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  display: flex;
}
.navbar .search-box input {
  padding: 12px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.navbar .search-box button {
  color: #999;
  border: navajowhite;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar a, .navbar .search-box, .navbar .search-icon {
    display: none;
    
  }
  .navbar a.icon {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar.responsive {position:relative;}
  .navbar.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
        right: 0;
    top: 0;
    
  }
  .navbar.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    
  }
  
  .navbar.responsive .search-box { 
    float: none;
    display: flex;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 4%;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }
  .navbar.responsive .search-icon{
    display: flex;
  }
}


/*--------------------------body------------------------*/


/* Column container */
.row {  
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* Create two unequal columns that sits next to each other */
/* Sidebar/left column */
.side {
  -ms-flex: 30%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 30%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Main column */
.main {   
  -ms-flex: 70%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 70%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Fake image, just for this example */
.fakeimg {
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 700px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .row {   
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 400px wide, make the navigation links stack on top of each other instead of next to each other 
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Footer is the issue. Remove css, which breaks navbar styles. Also meta tags should be in the header. Screenshot https://prnt.sc/1t7vjgu

Comment: yes, the menu is working properly now.

again, any idea why the 2 column at the content not working? It should be side by side in pc screen, but it never. But working well in the media screen.

Comment: .side { flex: 0.3; } .main { flex: 0.7; }

Comment: perfect now.....wondering why 30% 70% wouldn't work? Btw, TQVM...cheers.

Comment: It's a property with combination of components. The flex-grow property is only specified as a single number or decimal number (0–9). Here is a detailed answer with links to spec. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37618051/7303639