# Understanding the flex property

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why, in this example, is the `.main` element (blue) dividing space only with `.aside-1` (yellow) and `.aside-2` (pink), and not with all elements?

[image]

We have a wrapper that is putting all elements occupying one line.

In `.main` we say `flex: 3 0px`, which I think says, this element will be 3x bigger than the other four elements and will occupy 3/(3+1+1+1+1).

However, I've noticed that with a `nowrap` wrapper the smallest item is `.main`.

And with `wrap`, it divides with the two closest elements.

Can't understand this.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper>* {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.header {
  background: tomato;
}

.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.main {
  text-align: left;
  background: deepskyblue;
  height: 50vh;
  flex: 3 0px;
}

.aside-1 {
  background: gold;
}

.aside-2 {
  background: hotpink;
}

.aside {
  flex: 1 auto;
}

.aside-1 {
  order: 1;
}

.main {
  order: 2;
}

.aside-2 {
  order: 3;
}

.footer {
  order: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <article class="main">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </article>
  <aside class="aside aside-1">Aside 1</aside>
  <aside class="aside aside-2">Aside 2</aside>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First take a look at this rule in your code:

```
.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}
```

The selector above is targeting *all five flex items*:

- `header`
- `article`
- `aside`
- `aside`
- `footer`

The `flex` component breaks down to this:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1` (by default)
- `flex-basis: 100%`

You wrote:

> Why, in this example, is the `.main` element (blue) dividing space only with `.aside-1` (yellow) and `.aside-2` (pink), and not with all elements?

This is why:

1. The container is set to `flex-flow: row wrap`, meaning flex items are allowed to wrap.
2. As noted above, all flex items are set to `flex-basis: 100%` (i.e. `width: 100%`), meaning there can only be one flex item per row, *except...*
3. `flex-basis: 100%` only gets applied to the `header` and `footer` because...
4. it is being overridden by other rules later in the cascade sequence<sup>1</sup>:

   ```
   .main { flex: 3 0px; }

   .aside { flex: 1 auto; }
   ```

> However, I've noticed that with a `nowrap` wrapper the smallest item is `.main`.

Yes, because, as mentioned above, it has `flex-basis: 0` and `flex-shrink: 1`.

> In `.main` we say `flex: 3 0px`, which I think says, this element will be 3x bigger than the other four elements and will occupy 3/(3+1+1+1+1).

Not quite. `flex-grow: 3` means that the element will consume 3x the amount of free space than other flex items with `flex-grow: 1`. It doesn't necessarily mean it will be 3x the size. More details here: *[flex-grow not sizing flex items as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34644807/3597276)*

---

<sup>1</sup> It may appear that specificity should win over the cascade, and all items should get `flex-basis: 100%`:

- `.wrap > * { flex-basis: 100%; }` vs `.main { flex: 3 0px; }`
- `.wrap > * { flex-basis: 100%; }` vs `aside { flex: 1 auto; }`

Except that the [universal selector (`*`) has zero specificity](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity). So in this case, all selectors have equal specificity and source order matters.

Comment: Thank you very much @Michael_B :-) understood!