# Why does the flex shorthand property behave differently?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the below html code:

```
<div id="main">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>  
  <div>One, Two Three</div>
</div>
```

When I use

```
#main div {
 flex: 1;
 border: 1px solid;
}
```

All divs are equispaced. But when I expand it,

```
#main div {
 flex-grow:1;
 flex-shrink:1;
 flex-basis: auto;
 border: 1px solid;
}
```

the divs are not equispaced. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The dupe link clarifies this quite well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522388/reasons-to-use-flex-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `flex:1` it is the shorthand for `flex: 1 1 0` (in IE - is `flex:1 1 0px`) and not `flex: 1 1 auto`

Here is why:

[**Basic Values of flex**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common)

> **flex: `<positive-number>`**
>
> Equivalent to `flex: <positive-number> 1 0`. Makes the flex item flexible and sets the flex basis to zero, resulting in an item that
> receives the specified proportion of the free space in the flex
> container. If all items in the flex container use this pattern, their
> sizes will be proportional to the specified flex factor.

Comment: But if flex-basis default is 'auto' then why does it become 0px in shorthand? If possible, can you elaborate how the flex shorthand works?

Comment: @codingsplash added an explanation

Comment: I noticed you got an unjust downvote, which unfortunately is quite common ... and just wanted to say +1 from me because of that, but I did close this as a dupe though :)