# Image in flexbox column not rendering properly in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

I have a div with one image and one paragraph in it.

```
<div id="container">
  <img src="..." />
  <p>
    This is my text
  </p>
</div>
```

I use flex-box and `flex-direction: column` to align them.

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
}

img {
  max-width: 80%;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

p {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

Since both `img` and `p` have `flex-basis 50%` I would expect each of them to take up 50% of the space. In Firefox it works, but in Chrome the image is bigger (in height) than the container itself.

I have made a jsfiddle to demonstrate this: https://jsfiddle.net/q2esvro9/1/

How can I get the behaviour from Firefox in Chrome?

*(Another interesting fact: In Internet Explorer 11 the image and text take up the same space, but the image is stretched in width. Which means 3 different behaviours for a very short and simple CSS code)*

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: solid 2px red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
}

img {
  max-width: 80%;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

p {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  border: solid 2px green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/apple-logo_318-40184.jpg" />
  <p>
    This is my text
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure about why the browsers have different things going on here, but you could just add `max-height: 50%` for the img css I suppose

Comment: min-height:0 to the image will fix this

Comment: But it breaks the aspect ratio (on Chrome).

Comment: Not entirely a duplicate in my opinion because the solution here is a 2-step process. The duplicate covers only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are flexbox rendering variations between the major browsers.

When dealing with images, the number of variations grows.

What I've found to work consistently across browsers is to *not* use `img` elements in a [*flex formatting context*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers) (i.e., don't make them flex items).

Instead, wrap an `img` in a div element, making the div the flex item and keeping the image in a [*block formatting context*](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#block-formatting).

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: solid 2px red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
}

#container > div {
  flex: 0 0 50%;  /* 1 */
  min-height: 0;  /* 2 */
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  border: solid 2px green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/apple-logo_318-40184.jpg" />
  </div>
  <p>
    This is my text
  </p>
</div>
```

Notes:

1. [The meaning and benefits of flex: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48522388/3597276)
2. [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)