# Flexbox make one item 4x bigger than other items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am looking at this Flexbox cheat sheet:

http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html#wrapcolumn

Here we have an example:

[image]

I want to make the bigitem 4x bigger than the smallitem, not 2x as big, but I cannot figure out how to do that?! I tried substituting 4 for 2 and no that didn't work.

Comment: I tried flex: 4 0 0 ;

Comment: `flex: 4;` is different than `flex: 4 0 0;`. `flex: 4` is shorthand for `flex: 4 0 auto;`

Comment: I also tried flex-grow: 4 for the bigitem, that didn't work, I am trying this on Google Chrome.

Comment: I think the problem was that I had a div around a input tag, and I was adding the flex styles to the outer div not the input, not sure why adding to outer div did not work.

Comment: @chazsolo No, `flex: 4` is shorthand for `flex: 4 1 0`

Comment: Thanks @LGSon for the correction!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> I want to make the bigitem 4x bigger than the smallitem, not 2x as big, but I cannot figure out how to do that?!

Don't use `flex-grow` for this task. Use `flex-basis`.

```
.bigitem { flex: 0 0 80%; } /* flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */

.smallitem { flex: 0 0 20%; }
```

The `flex-grow` property does not actually size flex items. It distributes free space in the container.

So `flex: 4 0 0` on one item, and `flex: 1 0 0` on the other item, means the following:

- Determine the amount of free space on the main axis line (the row, in this case)
- Divide that amount by five.
- One item consumes four parts.
- The other item consumes one part.

Because you're dealing only with free space, the 4 vs 1 `flex-grow` doesn't necessarily mean one item will be 4x the size of the other. It means that one item will consume 4x more free space than the other.

It also means that `flex-grow` values of 8 vs 2, 16 vs 4, 20 vs 5, etc., will yield the exact same result, because the proportions are the same.

See here for more details:

- [flex-grow not sizing flex items as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34644807/3597276)
- [Make div fill remaining *horizontal* space in flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37745051/3597276)