# Flex-grow with width property on element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box1">One</div>
    <div class="box2">Two</div>
</div>


 .box1{
        background: red;
        width: 100px;
        flex-grow: 1;
    }

    .box2{
        background: green;
        flex-grow:1;
    }
```

And I see different width in columns : 
534px and 463px; Why ? 
flex-grow is identical

Comment: Well, as your _wrapper_ doesn't have `display: flex`, your `flex-grow` won't be applied since the child elements is not flex items.

Comment: i use display:flex for wrapper

Comment: No, can't see you do, please add a [mcve]

Comment: Furthermore, `flex-grow` make use of the available space left (parent width minus item content), and since one off your items is forced to start with 100px + each items content (for the left the bigger of set width/content), the remaining space is then shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because the `flex-grow` will make the element to consume the free space. In your case the first element has `100px` of width and the other one is having width equal to its content so the free space is `(width of container - 100px - content of box2)`. This free space will be split equally and added to both element and it's logical that the first one will be bigger since initially it was already bigger.

In your example, the second element is about `29px` and if we fix the width of the container to `600px` for example, we will have a free space equal to `471px` so both elements will end with `335.5px` and `264.5px` of width.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width:600px;
}

.box1 {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.box2 {
  background: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1">One</div>
  <div class="box2">Two</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are many dupes...

Comment: Thanks but how make equals ?

Comment: @zloctb You set `flex-basis` to `0`, (and remove width).

Comment: @LGSon actually I don't have in mind a dup that explain the calculation, if you know a good one added it ... I don't agree with the actual one because describing the difference between width and flex-grow will not help a lot

Comment: If you take a good look at the dupe answer, you'll find a link to an answer that does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644807/flex-grow-not-sizing-flex-items-as-expected ... still, updated the dupe link list with the same