# Is flexbox grow affected by flexbox-basis?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">one </div>
  <div class="box box2">two </div>
  <div class="box box3">three </div>
  <div class="box box4">four </div>
  <div class="box box5">five </div>
  <div class="box box6">six </div>
</div>
```

and styled it with this CSS using flexbox

```
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.box {
  flex-basis:500px;
  flex-grow:1;
}

.box3 {
  flex-grow:10;
}
```

I was assuming that `flex-grow:10;` would make `box 3` **10 times** larger that `box 4` that lands in my screen, but I see this:

[image]

**Why is this not 10 times bigger?**

Here is relative [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ichyr/pen/vpPmRP)

Comment: Here is a good explanation of what's happening: https://css-tricks.com/flex-grow-is-weird/

Comment: Because `flex-basis` is the **initial** width *before* other flex properties are affected. It's not clear what it is you are trying to do. Why are you using `flex-basis` at all?

Comment: `flex-grow` goes from 0 to 1 and it only defines the ability for the flex item to grow. Check this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @FerranBuireu That is incorrect. `flex-grow` define how many parts each items should get from the space left, in this case, based on the screenshot, 10/11 and 1/11 on the row with `box3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is flex-grow affected by flex-basis?

In a way, yes, as what `flex-grow` does is to distribute the *space left*, after the size of the items been reduced, where the items can be sized either by content or explicit set.

E.g., if the parent is 1000px wide, has 2 children where each child is 300px wide, the *space left* will be 1000px-300px-300px = 400px.

If one child has a flex grow value of 1 and the other has 10, the former will be 300px+(1/11*400px) and the latter 300px+(10/11*400px)

Read more here about `flex-grow`

- [Flex-grow not working as expected (flex items don't have the widths I expect)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927302/flex-grow-not-working-as-expected-flex-items-dont-have-the-widths-i-expect)
- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-grow-property

---

So in your case, where each item is set to 500px using, 2 per row, when there will be *space left*, that space will be shared equally on all row but the one with `box3`. On that row the space will be shared with 10/11 for `box3` and 1/11 for the other.

In case of 3 items per row, the shared for `box3` would be 10/12 and the other two 1/12 each.

---

> Why is this not 10 times bigger?

In this case, when a width is set on the item's, `flex-grow` distribute the *free space left* among the items.

If you want to use `flex-grow` to size the items, give them a `flex-basis` of `0`. That will make the calculations for `flex-grow` believe the items is empty, and by that it would be 10 times bigger.

```css
/* We start writing out flexbox here. The above is just page setup */
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.box {
  flex-basis:0;
  flex-grow:1;
  overflow: hidden;        /*  to allow items to be smaller
                               than its content  */
}

.box3 {
  flex-grow:10;
}


/* CSS Normalize */
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section,summary{display:block;}audio,canvas,video{display:inline-block;}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0;}[hidden]{display:none;}html{font-family:sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;}a:focus{outline:thin dotted;}a:active,a:hover{outline:0;}h1{font-size:2em;}abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted;}b,strong{font-weight:700;}dfn{font-style:italic;}mark{background:#ff0;color:#000;}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace, serif;font-size:1em;}pre{white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word;}q{quotes:\201C \201D \2018 \2019;}small{font-size:80%;}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline;}sup{top:-.5em;}sub{bottom:-.25em;}img{border:0;}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden;}fieldset{border:1px solid silver;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em;}button,input,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;margin:0;}button,input{line-height:normal;}button,html input[type=button],/* 1 */
input[type=reset],input[type=submit]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer;}button[disabled],input[disabled]{cursor:default;}input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio]{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;}input[type=search]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;}input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none;}textarea{overflow:auto;vertical-align:top;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}body,figure{margin:0;}legend,button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0;}

/* Box-sizing border-box */
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }


/* Some default styles to make each box visible */
.box {
  color:white;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow:4px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  padding:10px;
}

/* Colours for each box */
.box1 { background:#1abc9c;}
.box2 { background:#3498db;}
.box3 { background:#9b59b6;}
.box4 { background:#34495e;}
.box5 { background:#f1c40f;}
.box6 { background:#e67e22;}
.box7 { background:#e74c3c;}
.box8 { background:#bdc3c7;}
.box9 { background:#2ecc71;}
.box10 { background:#16a085;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">one </div>
  <div class="box box2">two </div>
  <div class="box box3">three </div>
  <div class="box box4">four </div>
  <div class="box box5">five </div>
  <div class="box box6">six </div>
</div>
```