# Line before and after title over image

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want to create a **line before and after a centered title**. The line and text must have a **transparent background** to be able to position them on a uneven background. The line must not be 100% width, like this:

[image: Centered text with line before and after over an image]

The text of the title can change:

- Width of title isn't known
- The title can span on several lines

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<h1>Today</h1>
```

Comment: The biggest problem is the image background. What have you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214127/css-technique-for-a-horizontal-line-with-words-in-the-middle

Comment: @DanMan, Yes, it is, if no background, i can set the text background to cover the line, then the line and text will have fixed width

Comment: @Rein: No, that question doesn't have the same requirements as this one. That's a fieldset which works in a certain defined way which is unlike this one.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can make a **line on both sides of the title** with 2 pseudo elements and borders:

- This works over a **transparent background** (lines and title have transparent backgrounds).
- The line length will adapt to the title width so they alway start and end at the same position regardless to title length.
- The  title can **span on several lines** while the left and right lines stay verticaly centered (*Note that you need to wrap the title in a `<span>` tag for this to work. See demo*)

[image: Title with line before and after over an image]

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300);
 body {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/EzOh4DX.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  width: 70%;
  margin: .7em auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight:300;
  color: #fff;
}
h1:before, h1:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 -55%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
h1:after {
  margin: 0 -55% 0 .5em;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<h1>Today</h1>
<h1>Today news</h1>
<h1><span>Today<br/>news</span></h1>
```

Comment: When have more text, the line and text's width will long

Comment: @juo I updated my answer to fit your needs.

Comment: Is it possible to turn the `h1` into a `img`?

Comment: @you can't just change the `h1` to an `img` tag as you can't add a pseudo element on `img`. But you can add the `img` tag in the `h1` element or change the `h1` to a `div` and put the `img` inside.

Answer (score 17):

Here is another approach by using flexbox display. The `flex-grow` property specifies how the free space should be distributed among the elements when their total size is smaller than container size.

By default no `width` is specified on the elements that produce the lines and they have no `content` (meaning they are basically empty and take up no space). However, the `flex-grow` setting on these elements would make the leftover space (total space of the container - space of the text) get equally distributed among them. This makes it look as though the line runs from end to the other except for where the text is.

**Solid line on either side of content:**

In the below snippet, a top to bottom gradient is used to produce the effect of having a solid line on either side of the content.

```css
h3{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.heading:before, .heading:after,
.heading-ie span.after, .heading-ie span.before{
  content: '';
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white, white);
  background-size: 100% 2px;
  background-position: 0% 50%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

/* Just for demo*/
body{
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<h3 class='heading'>Something broader</h3>
<h3 class='heading'>Something broader and broader</h3>
<h3 class='heading'>Something broader<br/> and spans multiple <br/> no. of lines</h3>

<!-- IE11 specific version -->

<h3 class='heading-ie'>
  <span class='before'></span> <!-- IE11 supports flex-grow only on actual elements -->
  Something broader and broader and broader
  <span class='after'></span> <!-- IE11 supports flex-grow only on actual elements -->
</h3>
```

[image]

---

**Line with Gradient Effect on either side of content:**

In the below snippet, a thin left to right gradient is used to produce the effect of a line which goes from a solid color near the content to transparent on the other side.

```css
h3{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.heading:before, .heading:after,
.heading-ie span.after, .heading-ie span.before{
  content: '';
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  background-size: 100% 2px;
  background-position: 0% 50%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.heading:before, .heading-ie span.before{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, white);
}
.heading:after, .heading-ie span.after{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, transparent, white);
}

/* Just for demo*/
body{
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<h3 class='heading'>Something broader</h3>
<h3 class='heading'>Something broader and broader</h3>
<h3 class='heading'>Something broader<br/> and spans multiple <br/> no. of lines</h3>

<!-- IE11 specific version -->

<h3 class='heading-ie'>
  <span class='before'></span> <!-- IE11 supports flex-grow only on actual elements -->
  Something broader and broader and broader
  <span class='after'></span> <!-- IE11 supports flex-grow only on actual elements -->
</h3>
```

[image]

<sup>**Note:** In the snippet I have used an extra `span` elements for the lines because IE11 doesn't seem to support `flex-grow` on pseudo-elements. Otherwise, the same can be achieved with a pseudo-element also.</sup>

---

**Drawback** of this approach is the browser support for this feature, which is pretty low at the moment. You may also have to adopt some browser specific customizations that are detailed in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898287/how-to-display-text-a-dotted-line-then-more-text-spanning-the-width-of-the-page/28629080#28629080) which is similar to this.

At present this doesn't give anything extra over web-tiki's answer but is just another possible option. This approach would **be more helpful in cases like the below**:

```css
h3{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.heading-ie .start, .heading-ie .middle, .heading-ie .end{
  content: '';
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white, white);
  background-position: 0% 50%;
  background-size: 100% 2px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

/* Order specifies the order in which the elements should be presen within container */

.content-1{
  order: 2;
}
.start{
  order: 1;
}
.middle{
  order: 3;
}
.content-2{
  order: 4;
}
.end{
  order: 5;
}

/* Just for demo*/

body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<h3 class='heading-ie'>
  <span class='start'></span> <!-- IE11 supports flex-grow only on actual elements -->
  <span class='content-1'>Text here</span>
  <span class='middle'></span> <!-- IE11 supports flex-grow only on actual elements -->
  <span class='content-2'>and here too</span>
  <span class='end'></span> <!-- IE11 supports flex-grow only on actual elements -->
</h3>

<h3 class='heading-ie'>
  <span class='start'></span> <!-- IE11 supports flex-grow only on actual elements -->
  <span class='content-1'>Text with <br/> line break</span>
  <span class='middle'></span> <!-- IE11 supports flex-grow only on actual elements -->
  <span class='content-2'>and here with <br/> line break too</span>
  <span class='end'></span> <!-- IE11 supports flex-grow only on actual elements -->
</h3>
```

[image]