# Angular Material way of making a horizontal line with word in the middle

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

Using [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/), I'm trying to create a horizontal line with a word in the middle. Something pretty similar to the one displayed [here](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/signin).

I've tried this and it's close but I'd like the lines to be vertically aligned to the middle of the word **or**.

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="center start">
  <md-divider flex></md-divider>
  <div style="flex: 0 1 auto;">or</div>
  <md-divider flex></md-divider>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/devotis/a7m6xrwy/

I guess, I need styled `<hr>`'s left and right. How can I improve this code and remain within the ways of Angular Material?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584120/line-separator-under-text-and-transparent-background

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A nice way to do it is to use the layout="row" along with flex.

```
<span layout="row"><hr flex/>or<hr flex/></span>
```

JS fiddle applying this idea to the button text: http://jsfiddle.net/a7m6xrwy/1/

You can style the hr attribute with css. The md-divider directive isn't meant to be used this way, so there is no reason to try and force it. If you wish to use a directive to solve this issue, you will have to write your own md-divider directive which takes the display text as a parameter.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a solution using material's `mat-divider`:

```html
<h1>Divider with text</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div class="line"><mat-divider></mat-divider></div>
  <div class="text mat-typography">Hey there</div>
  <div class="line"><mat-divider></mat-divider></div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.line {
  flex: 1;
}

.text {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

The result will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

For people using angular material 2 and [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout), here's my solution. Not entirely satisfactory, but it does the trick.

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" fxLayoutGap="5px">
  <mat-divider fxFlex="1 0"></mat-divider>
  <div>or</div>
  <mat-divider fxFlex="1 0"></mat-divider>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work like a charm.

```
<mat-divider style="width: 40%; display: inline-block;"></mat-divider>
<span style="padding: 20px; font-weight: 500;">Or</span>
<mat-divider style="width: 40%; display: inline-block;"></mat-divider>
```

PS: You may extract the inline styles into meaningful CSS classes. Avoided it here for brevity.

Output:

[image: Output]