# Draw line after a title with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

How can I draw a line like after title text like this :

"TITLE ________"

In *CSS*?
The "_" should complete the rest of the div and fill the remaining space.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far in a jsfiddle or similar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584120/line-separator-under-text-and-transparent-background/23584310#23584310) :

```css
h1{
  overflow:hidden;
}
h1:after{
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  margin-right:-100%;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
<h1>Longer Title</h1>
```

Comment: Ok it's completely what i need there is other solution compatible with IE 6 ? Tanks

Comment: @Olaf please dont send in tanks! and pseudo elements are not supported in ie6, and there aren't many people using ie6

Comment: what if we have 2 line heading. the line should fill first line as suggested by your answer and second line should fill whole space. see this link for reference image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ4gJ.jpg

Answer (score 4):

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
}

h1:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title Here</h1>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
h1:after {
    content: "__________________";
}
```

Further explanation and examples: [:after pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

Comment: The "_" will complete all the rest of the div ?

Comment: No, it won´t. It will be as long as you type _ in it.

Comment: If you dont want a specific length, you should go with the other solutions that use a border.