# A Line with some text in the left

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a horizontal rule with some text in the left. For example:

[image: Like This]

How to achieve it with CSS ?

I have done this But didn't get the expected result

```
h2 { width:100%; text-align:center; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; line-
height:0.1em; margin:10px 0 20px; } 
h2 span { background:#fff; padding:0 10px; }
```

Comment: Check out [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) and see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/no3s54ro/

Comment: Thanks @Marvin :)

Comment: After reading your question more carefully, for your scenario the `:after` element will do the job. For the line to fill the remaining space on the right, have a look at *[Title with lines filling remaining space on both sides](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30591488/3162554)* or some of the other questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

A line can occupy space left by the text (fluiiiid), with the wonders of Flexbox: **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/VbJzNb?editors=0100)**

No need for a span: the line is a :pseudo.
Layout should be possible with a table *layout* (CSS, not markup) for better compatibility but I don't care of IE8/9.

```css
h2 {
  display: flex;
    justify-content: stretch;
    align-items: baseline;
  margin: 0.625rem 0 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #444;
} 

h2:after {
  content: '';
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<h2>work</h2>
<!-- SO 44257291 -->
```