# Moving div down without moving rest of the content

Tags: html, css

I have a border I am trying to align vertically with some text and every time I try and move it down the rest of my content moves down making it impossible to complete this task. As you can see in my picture below, the border is above the text and I want it vertically aligned.

[image]

```css
#work {
  color: #a5a5a5;
  font-family: Hobo Std;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
}
.leftrule {
  border-top: 2px solid #a5a5a5;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 30%;
}
.videos {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.dancer-vid-left {
  background-image: url(images/dancer2.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 300px;
}
#video1 {
  border: 15px solid #373636;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 8px rgba(55, 54, 54, .3);
  background-color: #373636;
  width: 480px;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftrule"></div>
<p id="work">My Work!</p>
</div>
<div class="rightrule"></div>

<div class="row videos">
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div id="video1">
    <iframe frameborder="0" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Q3bEF0PHR00" width="450"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div id="video2">
    <iframe frameborder="0" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Q3bEF0PHR00" width="450"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have your tried positioning? like `position:relative;` or `position:absolute;`?

Comment: I wanted to stick to normal flow. I want to try and stay away from positioning if possible.

Comment: You say you want it aligned, aligned to where?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23584310/2591007) what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want it aligned to the middle of the text either side. I would use `:before` and `:after` pseudo selectors for this task.

```css
#workcontainer {
  text-align: center;  
}
#work {
  color: #a5a5a5;
  font-family: Hobo Std;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block; /* This element needs to not flow the whole width, so we place it in a container and inline-block this */
}
#work:before, #work:after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 2px solid #a5a5a5;
  width: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
#work:before {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left:20px;
}
#work:after {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="workcontainer">
  <p id="work">My Work!</p>
</div>
```

Just increase or decrease the margin to move the lines closer or further away.

Comment: I totally misread OP's post, until I read your answer.  I removed my answer since it was so far off.

Comment: @DSMann8 I posted a comment asking them to clarify because they don't actually specify where they want it aligning to. I've used my best judgement based upon them wanting to move it down. I don't think it's an accident that 2 other people came to the same conclusion and gave a similar answer to you ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've interpreted it right.  The OP say's he want's to move the div down, not over.  That along with the fact that his markup has both a left and right rule adds credence to your answer. I've submitted an edit making this more clear.