# Placing line to left and right of heading text

Tags: html, css

I want to create a line separator before and after a title. The line and text must have a transparent background to be able to position them on a textured background.

I am trying to take this approach:
[Line before and after title over image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584120/line-before-and-after-centered-text-over-transparent-background)

However, my lines are on top and bottom instead of left and right:

```
<div class="widget widget-catalogsale-products">
    <div class="page-title category-title">
        <h1>Special products</h1>
    </div>
</div>

.widget.widget-catalogsale-products {display: block;}
.widget-catalogsale-products { 
    background: url(../images/widget-catalogsale-products.gif) repeat left top; 
    margin-left: -500px; 
    padding-left: 500px;
    margin-right: -500px;
    padding-right: 500px;
    padding-top: 106px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 46px;
}
.widget-catalogsale-products .page-title h1 {
    color: #548891;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:1.2em;
}
.widget-catalogsale-products .page-title h1:before,
.widget-catalogsale-products .page-title h1:after {
    content:'';
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
    height:0.65em;
    border-bottom:7px solid #e3edef;
    margin:0 2% 0 55%;
}
.widget-catalogsale-products .page-title h1:after {
    margin:0 55% 0 2%;
}
.widget-catalogsale-products .price-box .price-label {display:none;}
.widget-catalogsale-products .mini-products-list .product-name {margin-left: 0;}
.widget-catalogsale-products .product-name {margin-bottom: 5px;}
.widget-catalogsale-products .block-content li.item { border: 0; padding:0 0 25px 0; }
.widget-catalogsale-products .products-grid {margin-bottom: 0;}
.widget-catalogsale-products .products-grid .product-image {padding: 5px; border: 0;}
.widget-catalogsale-products .products-grid .product-image:before {border-width: 5px; border-color: #D2B696;}
.widget-catalogsale-products .products-grid .product-name a {color: #fff;}
```

Can anyone find the bug in my CSS?
http://jsfiddle.net/6o9m30tv/

Comment: Change `margin:0 2% 0 -55%;` and `margin:0 -55% 0 2%;` http://jsfiddle.net/6o9m30tv/3/

Comment: @NenadVracar, thank you, that was the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing comma/minus in your margin. Change it like this:

```
.widget-catalogsale-products .page-title h1:after {
    content:'';
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
    height:0.65em;
    border-bottom:7px solid #e3edef;
    margin:0 2% 0 -55%;
}
.widget-catalogsale-products .page-title h1:after {
    margin:0 -55% 0 2%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the margin sizes you set was causing the pseudo elements to break to the next line..

here is a snippet how I got it to align and the codes i commented out

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300);
body{
    background-image: url(http://fr.playstation.com/media/5ZfqPjVF/BigSkyInfinity_Hero_EN.JPG);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% auto;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.widget.widget-catalogsale-products {display: block;}
.widget-catalogsale-products { 
 background: url(../images/widget-catalogsale-products.gif) repeat left top; 
 margin-left: -500px; 
 padding-left: 500px;
 margin-right: -500px;
 padding-right: 500px;
 padding-top: 106px;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 46px;
}
.widget-catalogsale-products .page-title h1 {
 color: #548891;
 width:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 overflow:hidden;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:1.2em;
}
.widget-catalogsale-products .page-title h1:before,
.widget-catalogsale-products .page-title h1:after {
 content:'';
 vertical-align:top;
 display:inline-block;
 width:20%;
 height:0.65em;
 border-bottom:2px solid #e3edef;
 /*margin:0 2% 0 55%;*/
} 
/*.widget-catalogsale-products .page-title h1:after {
 margin:0 55% 0 2%; 
} */
.widget-catalogsale-products .price-box .price-label {display:none;}
.widget-catalogsale-products .mini-products-list .product-name {margin-left: 0;}
.widget-catalogsale-products .product-name {margin-bottom: 5px;}
.widget-catalogsale-products .block-content li.item { border: 0; padding:0 0 25px 0; }
.widget-catalogsale-products .products-grid {margin-bottom: 0;}
.widget-catalogsale-products .products-grid .product-image {padding: 5px; border: 0;}
.widget-catalogsale-products .products-grid .product-image:before {border-width: 5px; border-color: #D2B696;}
.widget-catalogsale-products .products-grid .product-name a {color: #fff;}
```

```html
<div class="widget widget-catalogsale-products">
        <div class="page-title">
            <h1>Special products</h1>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I simply needed to use negative margin instead of positive.