# How to give space in the middle of hr tag?

Tags: html, css

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/vezz82tr/

*HTML Code:*

```
<div>
Section 1...
</div>
<hr>
<div>
Section 2...
</div>
```

*CSS Code:*

```
hr {
  border: 0;
  border-top: 4px double white;
  text-align: center;
}
hr:after {
  content: '\2665';
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -12px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

As you can see, there is a icon in the middle of the hr. I want to give some **space** in the middle of the hr, so the lines will not be above or below the icon. Any suggestions?

Comment: you could just put margin: 15px or so for the hr css

Comment: Its an option, but Its will cut from the sides and not from the middle. @ClearBoth

Comment: Can you change HTML?

Comment: Change to what? @NenadVracar

Comment: Do you mean to say that the `hr` should be cut into two pieces? One on the left, then the icon in the middle and one on the right?

Comment: Exactly Harry. @Harry

Comment: Have a look at the two options in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584120/line-before-and-after-title-over-image. They produce only one line and not two but should give you the idea.

Comment: Flexbox is exactly the reason why I linked the above (my answer) but I would like to caution you that flexbox has lesser support than web-tiki's answer in that thread. And no, I am not saying this question/answer is a duplicate because it is slightly different from the other.

Comment: Yes, thank you for this information Harry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with **Flexbox**

```css
.line {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

hr {
  border: 0;
  border-top: 4px double black;
  flex: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}

i:after {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;
  padding: 20px;
  content: '\2665';
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <hr>
    <i class="heart"></i>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad i could help, here is example with Font-awesome https://jsfiddle.net/vezz82tr/3/