# Why I can't adjust line to be width 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wan't to set line full width, from text on left side.

If text have one word with 5 letters to be like this:

[image]

and if text have 3 words to be like this:

[image]

Can someone help me, here is what I tried to solve my problem, but it's not semantic useful

https://jsfiddle.net/xoty99bc/

```
<h3>
Lorem
</h3><div class"line">

</div>


h3{
  display:inline-block;
  width:20%;
}
div{
  display:inline-block;
  height:2px;
  width:80%;
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Your HTML needs to be `<div class="line">`.  It was missing the `=` and presumably your CSS wants to then refer to `.line`.

Comment: ok, thats not problem, in css I called div element to set atributes

Comment: When things aren't working, one of the FIRST things you do is fix all your illegal HTML.  It may not be the issue, but it could be contributing or confusing the issue on some browsers.

Comment: Related: [Line before and after title over image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584120/line-before-and-after-title-over-image)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **Flexbox** and [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo element. Or if you dont want to use `:after` you can do it like this [`Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/xoty99bc/4/)

```css
h3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

h3:after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Lorem ipsum </h3>
```

Comment: What is the browser support for this technique?

Comment: Thank you bro!
Svaka cast brate, ovo je odlicno

Answer (score 0):

Take this as an idea:
https://jsfiddle.net/86hy152p/

```
h3{
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:
}
.line {
  display:inline-block;
  height:2px;
  width:80%;
  background-color:red;
}
```

You can adjust the height / position of the red bar later with margin and padding.