# Diagonal dashed pattern on each the side of paragraph

Tags: html, css

```html
<div class="search">
  <p>SEARCH</p>
</div>
```

[image: dashed pattern on each side of a word]

I am trying to add a dashed lateral padding like in the image. Only in the sides of the text. Is there any way I can do that ?

Comment: Well, you could do it with an image

Comment: AFAIK the only way to do this would be with an image. I would recommend you set it as a background image, and then give the letters a white `background-color`. That's probably the easiest way, as opposed to making two smaller images to fit on either side. Edit: Web-Tiki's answer below is much better, CSS will work more smoothly and will take less time to load than an image. Do what he said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use linear gradient for the pattern and the technique described in [Line before and after title over image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23584310/1811992) to position it on each side of the title.
It would be something like this:

```css
.search {
  margin: .7em auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left:100px;
}
.search:before, .search:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%; height:0.8em;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 -105%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #E0E0E0 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, #E0E0E0 50%, #E0E0E0 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-size: 0.5em 0.5em;
}
.search:after {
  margin: 0 -105% 0 .5em;
}
.search p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <p>SEARCH</p>
</div>
<div class="search">
  <p>MOST POPULAR</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could to this with `Flexbox`, [`repeating-linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient) and `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements.

```css
.pattern {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
.pattern:before,
.pattern:after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #E1E1E1;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 2px, white 2px, white 6px);
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.pattern:before {
  flex: 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search pattern">
  <p>SEARCH</p>
</div>

<div class="search pattern">
  <p>MOST POPULAR</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this:

```
 div.search{
    width: 100%;
    backgroud-image: url('way/to/bg.png');
  }

div.search < p {
  background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```