# Centering the text with CSS, fill with a separator line in empty areas

Tags: html, css

##### Summary

I want to create an element where the date is centered, and on the left and right sides, there should be a line (like `<hr>`) filling the empty space.

##### Sample (what I would like to create)

[image: The result that I want]

##### My attempt (code snippet)

I have tried several different approaches to achieve this, but my knowledge is still limited. Could you please explain how I could accomplish my goal?

```css
.post-container .blog-post .post-date hr {
  color: #212931;
  width: 30%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.post-date .right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.post-date p {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-15px);
  color: #212931;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-date">
  <hr class="left" />
  <p>2023/06/25</p>
  <hr class="right" />
</div>
```

Comment: There are a lot of discussions that can help you. Check these for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214127/css-technique-for-a-horizontal-line-with-words-in-the-middle
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584120/line-before-and-after-title-over-image

Answer (score 5):

Avoid using old HTML elements, such as `<hr>`. Instead, use modern solutions like `display: grid` or `display: flex`, and pseudo-elements such as `::before` and `::after`

```css
.post-date {
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px; /* padding between line and text */
  align-items: center;
}

.post-date::before, .post-date::after {
  flex: 1;
  content: '';
  padding: 1px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-date">2023/06/25</div>
```

### More information

[`display: flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) - MDN
[`gap: 20px` - flex/grid property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap) - MDN

[`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) - MDN
[`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) - MDN

Comment: Truly a beautiful solution! - You can use the `gap: 20px` property (`.post-date` class) to create spacing between the line and text. This is a setting for containers with flex display.