# CSS - Create a custom dotted line out divs

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to create a line with circles. Can this be done with `background-repeat`? Or do I need to set a picture as background? The circles should have a 5px radius.

```
p:after {
   content: '';
   background: 'rounded div of size 10x10px' repeat-x
   width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Please, provide code or fiddle, hard to understand what you want.

Comment: [update] `border: 10px dotted black;` ?

Comment: @DariuszSikorski dots with 10x10px size

Comment: @vuvu updated my answer.

Comment: @DariuszSikorski but these are not rounded, like border-radius: 50%

Comment: @vuvu, Maybe create a fiddle for this, it's really hard to understand Your question.

Comment: Create an image with your expected result.

Comment: You seem to be looking for some like the gradient provided in my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898287/how-to-display-text-a-dotted-line-then-more-text-spanning-the-width-of-the-page/28629080#28629080. Look at the gradient used within the `.row:after` selector.

Comment: @timo I added a picture,  the circles should have a 5px radius

Comment: @vuvu Your picture doesn't realy clarify it, how is this not just achieved with a `border: dotted 10px lightgrey;` ? http://jsfiddle.net/0bj9wexd/

Just found out that Chrome interprets dotted borders different from Firefox. Which is probably your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the only solution without using `background-image` or `border-image` encoded in base64 or using external files.

https://jsfiddle.net/3r6xsr0m/

html:

```
<div class="line"></div>
```

css:

```
.line:before {
    content: "..................................................................................................";
    display: block;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: Georgia;
    color: #aaa;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Dots may differ depending of browser font rendering algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a 10px x 10px image of the dot and then use your method of repeating the background using either pseudo or just a new element. I'd go with a new div element if you can to prevent any issues across browsers like IE8. You'll also have to give your element a width if you go pseudo.