# Padding with dashes in html/css

Tags: html, css

I have a user managment block on my website and I'm trying to display a bit information there. 
I think that nothing is better than example with pictures. 
This is how the block looks now:

[image]

And this is how I want the block to look like:

[image: Target Block]

Is there any good way to do that? I added those dashes manually, and this is not the way I'm looking for, **I want it responsive**.

Here is the block code:

```html
<div class="account-box">
 Welcome, guess. <br>
 <hr>
 Coins: <span style="float: right;">0</span> <br>
 Points: <span style="float: right;">0</span> <br>
 Total Referrals: <span style="float: right;">0</span> <br>
 <hr>
 Logged as [username] <span style="text-align: right;"><a href="/logout" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><span class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></span>Logout</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: Please provide the code you have currently

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898287/how-to-display-text-a-dotted-line-then-more-text-spanning-the-width-of-the-page/28629080#28629080 (although that one is about dots instead of dashes, the approaches will 99% be the same).

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/leaders.en.html

Comment: Code has been added. forgot it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to do something similar. Here's what I came up with:

```css
.entry {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.entry>.spacer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed currentColor;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
  Label:
  <ins class="spacer"></ins>
  123
</div>
```

Adjust as needed!

Comment: It works fine! thank you. What do I need to do for streching the dashes for the whole line, until the other side? because it stops after few dashes.

Comment: @guyshitz Make sure the container spans the full width of the parent element, perhaps?