# Still trying to CSS style a table of contents

Tags: html, css, tableofcontents

In a couple of earlier questions, I've been trying to replicate the following table of contents:

[image]

Some suggestions have been helpful, but the "A REVIEW..." part is still broken: see [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/UvazAH/2) or a variation at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5Yje/).

The CSS is as follows:

```
.list li {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:330px;}

.list li:after {
    font-family: Times New Roman;
    font-size: 120%;
    content:"...............";
    text-indent: -1px;
    display:block;
    letter-spacing:34px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index:-1;
    font-weight:bold;}

.list li span {
    display:inline;
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding-right:5px;}

.list li .number {
    float:right;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-left:8px;}
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508732/table-of-contents-leading-dots

Comment: @PaulProgrammer No duplicate there. The problem here is the indentation and line-wrapping of the "A REVIEW..." part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very simple fix. Just change the `left` setting for the "..." pseudo element to `1em`.

```
.list li:after {
    left:1em;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/Y5Yje/5/)

---

**Update:**

There was an issue with the location of the right number when the title is wrapped to a second line. It can be fixed by adding a class called "two-lines".

```
<li style="margin:0 0 .5em 0; padding-left:.6em;" class="two-lines">
    <span>A REVIEW OF THE PRINCIPAL QUESTIONS IN MORALS</span>
    <span class="number">1</span>
</li>

.two-lines {
     text-indent:-.6em; /* This was already on the inline-style */
}

.two-lines .number {
    padding-right: 0.8em; /* This is fixing the number's location issue */
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/Y5Yje/7/)

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution introduces a new problem: the page number 1 has been shifted to the right. Do you know how to correct for this problem?

Comment: @76987 This is happening on the original fiddle as well. I'll try and fix that

Comment: On my end, the number is still shifted to the right: http://i.imgur.com/Bg308T3.png

Comment: @76987 Did you enter the new link at the end of my post? I've just checked it again on FF and Chrome

Comment: Oops, sorry, the update wasn't showing up until I refreshed the page. Unfortunately, once I [correct the location of the dots by changing `text-indent: -1px;` to `text-indent: -20px;`](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5Yje/8/), one of the original problems returns (dots in unwanted places).

Comment: Fixed by adding `.list .two-lines:after {
    text-indent: 19px;
}` http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/Y5Yje/9/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36999/discussion-between-76987-and-itay)

Comment: I'm sorry this is such a hassle. Unfortunately, when I adjust INDEX to be indented along with the second line, the kludge falls apart again: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5Yje/10/