# CSS style for leading dots

Tags: html, css, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm working on a CSS style which produces dots for a table of contents page. The code is based on https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=1073.

The idea is to create a div with lots of dots in it and overlay it with a span-elements (text and page-number), which have a white background.

This works quite good, except for following two issues:

1. dots are "cut" (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmpSj.png)
2. if a text-element requires more than one line, it doesn't get displayed

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:outline="http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/outline"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
                doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
                indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="outline:outline">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Table of Contents</title>
                <style>
                    body {
                    padding: 0cm;
                    font-family: "Georgia";
                    font-size: 12pt;
                    }
                    h1 {
                    text-align: left;
                    font-size: 18pt;
                    font-family: "Georgia";
                    font-weight: Normal;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0 0 0 0mm;
                    }
                    /* We set the height of the DIV and place the link and page number absolutely.
                    The DIV is filled with dots, but these are hidden by the link and span which have a white
                    background.
                    */
                    div {
                    position: relative;
                    height: 16pt;
                    line-height: 16pt;
                    padding: 0;
                    margin: 4pt 0 2pt 0;
                    white-space: nowrap;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    }
                    a, span {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    display: inline-block;
                    line-height: 16pt;
                    background-color: white;
                    }
                    a {
                    left: 0;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: black;
                    }
                    span {
                    right: 0;
                    text-align: right;
                    padding-left: 4pt;
                    }
                    ul {
                    padding-left: 0;
                    list-style: none;
                    }
                    ul ul {
                    font-size: 100%;
                    padding-left: 0em;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Table of Contents</h1>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="outline:item/outline:item"/>
                </ul>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="outline:item">
        <li>
            <xsl:if test="@title!=''">
                <div>. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                    <a>
                        <xsl:if test="@link">
                            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@link"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="@backLink">
                            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@backLink"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
                    </a>
                    <span>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@page"/>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </xsl:if>
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="outline:item"/>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Does anyone know how I could fix those issues?
Thanks!

Comment: Since this issue seems to be related to the HTML/CSS part of your code can you update your question with the rendered output and then maybe put that in a fiddle for us to view the issues you are having? Or at least provide an XML that causes the issues you are seeing so we can replicate it ourselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you were looking for a CSS solution, but just for fun, I created a JavaScript version of this.  (I don't know if it's possible to avoid the cut dots using pure CSS.)

```
$("a").each(function(){
    var rowHeight = $(this).height();
    while ($(this).height() === rowHeight) {
        $(this).append(" .");
    }
    $(this).html($(this).html().slice(0,-2));
});
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/9MJsz/

Comment: Thanks andi, this looks very promising. I've tried all kind of CSS variants, this might solve the problem. Will get back to you in a few hours!

Answer (score 3):

Its not exactly the same as what you're currently doing, but you could simply have each item in a `div` element with `border-bottom:1px dotted #000;`.

Alternatively, take a [look here for a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508732/table-of-contents-leading-dots), [and relevant CSS answer](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/leaders.en.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried the W3 method and it fixes the second issue, but the "cut" dots are still there.

Comment: You likely cant solve this using pure CSS (unless you do a lot manually). You'll need to use some JS which works out the width of the text of the entry, the width of the text for its page number and the remaining width that should be populated with dots, then taking into account the width of a dot plus a space before the next dot, offset the dot image accordingly so none are cut off. Depending on how keen you are to avoid the symptom described...this may be overkill.

Comment: Or...add a margin/padding amount to your page names so at least dots arent immediately overlapping...

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be ideal, you could try 2 things to get rid of (or lessen) the "cut" dots and bad appearance.  First, reduce the size of the dots.  The smaller the dots the less likely and less noticeable the issue is.  Second, put a space after the chapter name.  This would prevent 2 dots from being really close like you showed in your screenshot.

Reducing the size of the dots might also aid in showing the difference between the dots at the end of chapter names and the leading dots.

Obviously, this is not an ideal solution.