# How to display lists of dots that connect the chapter names and the chapter page numbers like a book table of content?

Tags: html, css

Using HTML and/or CSS is there a way to display lists of dots that connect the chapter names and the chapter page numbers like a book table of content:

- some chapter name ................... 1
- another chapter name .............. 21
- final chapter name .................. 143

My current markup is:

```html
<ol>
  <li><a href="">some chapter name</a><span class="toc-page-number">1</span>
  <li><a href="">another chapter name</a><span class="toc-page-number">21</span>
  <li><a href="">final chapter name</a><span class="toc-page-number">143</span>
</ol>
```

[Example of book table of content](http://www.disabilityinthefamily.com/book_TOCpage1.gif)

Comment: That solution uses a dot image to achieve this with CSS only. If you don't want to use images, [this other solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910336/css-style-for-leading-dots) achieves a better result (IMHO) using very little JavaScript.

Comment: indeed a solution is in the question marked as having already the answer

Comment: But the solutions that you got here are also very creative.

Answer (score 1):

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/899gn/) certainly is a hack but it does what you are asking for.

I added a `hr` tag in your li, i floated right your number.

The hr is styled with a bottom border `dotted` and it is absolutely positioned.

The problem was we were seeing the dot under the text, so I added a white background to those elements.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly with a pseudo element (IE8+)

[**Codepen Example**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ybrtk)

**HTML**

```
<ol>
  <li><a href="">some chapter name</a><span class="toc-page-number">1</span>
  <li><a href="">another chapter name</a><span class="toc-page-number">21</span>
  <li><a href="">final chapter name</a><span class="toc-page-number">143</span>
</ol>
```

**CSS**

```
ol {
  width:500px;
  margin:25px auto;
  border:1px solid grey;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  margin-bottom:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

li a {
  text-transform:uppercase;
  text-decoration:none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
   padding-left:10px;
  background-color: white; /* required*/ 
}

li span {
  float:right;
  position: relative;
  padding-right:10px;
}

li span:before {
  content:"";
  width:999px;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:-1px;
  right:100%;
  z-index:0;
  border-bottom:1px dotted black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using javascript or jquery, I have two suggestions:

One is putting a .div between the two elements (the chapter name and the page number) that has a `border-bottom-style: dotted`. This won't look ideal, but it should get the job done.

Or another (and probably way better) choice could be to make an element between the two that has an arbitrary number of '...' and then making `overflow-x: hidden`, which would force the dots to cut off.

This would require the new middle element to fill in the space between the page and title. This is best accomplished by putting both the title and page number before the dots in the html, then floating the title left and the page number right. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Renson/y236C/