# Dot leaders with picture background

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm building a website for a restaurant and I'm in a pickle. I'm trying to create the menu there. The idea is to align the food name to the left, the price to the right and fill the gap between them with dots. Like this

Hamburger ............................................ $ 4.00

XXL Hamburger .................................... $ 4.00

Milkshake .............................................. $ 4.00

I found a couple of solutions, which only work if you have a background with one color and no texture. The idea was to fill the whole line with dots and set the name/price background span with the same color as the site background, so the dots wouldn't show. But I have a picture for the background.

I'm not going to post my code here, because it wouldn't really matter or help.

Is it even possible? Doesn't have to be css only, might as well be done with JavaScript.

Comment: You could use a gradient...

Comment: Tip: `border-bottom: 1px dotted #000`.

Comment: "for a restaurant" ... "in a pickle" - lol

Comment: @Marty Thanks for the tip, but it's not good enough. I need the dots higher, to look like a part of the text or font.

Comment: @JacobGray You mean gradient background?

Comment: I had that in an answer but realized you needed to have this on a non-solid background.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/leaders

Comment: Do you want the dots? or you just use them for align?? If you want the dots but you don't want to see them you can use color: transparent, if you don't need the dots, align it in a table/ float div/ whatever, do not use dots if you don't need them(!)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508732/create-leading-dots-in-css this questions have some interesting answers. Not all of them use background color. This one for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25212853/2774496

Comment: Have you readen this: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/leaders.en.html ?

Comment: @MihkelAllorg look at my example in the answers. You can easily position the dots with position: relative; and a pixel value for the direction.

Comment: @marty you could just do a radial gradient, half black, half transparent.

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping someone would top my javascript answer with a CSS only solution, but so far it seems without javascript either the dots won't go all the way to the price, or the decimal places don't line up.

Comment: This is a great problem for coder golf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to do with some simple javascript and css, here's a fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4jn6vqb/1/)

The key is to set the width of the div that holds the dots to the width of the column minus the width of the food name minus the width of the price, and to make sure there are more than enough dots to cover the distance, and to set overflow: hidden for the dot div.

```
$(".menu-row").each(function(index, element) {
    var menuRowWidth = $(element).width();
    var foodItemWidth = $(element).children('.food-item').width();
    var priceWidth = $(element).children('.price').width();
    var $dotFiller = $(element).children('.dot-filler');
    var dotFillerWidth = menuRowWidth - foodItemWidth - priceWidth;
    $dotFiller.width(dotFillerWidth + "px"); 
});
```

Then float the item and dot div left, the price right, all within a set width column.  It's also important that overflow: hidden is set for the dots, because when we set the width of that div in javascript we want all extra dots to just be cut off.  The CSS:

```
.food-item {
  float: left
}

.dot-filler {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  float: left;
}

.price {
  float: right;
}

.menu-row {
  width: 400px;
}
```

Then structure your html as follows:

```
<div class="menu-row">
  <div class="food-item">Steak</div>
  <div class="dot-filler">............................................................................................</div>
  <div class="price">$18.00</div>
</div>

<div class="menu-row">
  <div class="food-item">Hamburger</div>
  <div class="dot-filler">............................................................................................</div>
  <div class="price">$8.00</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am kinda late, but you can quite easily do it with a radial-gradient:

```css
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.names span {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

.prices span {
  display: block;
  text-align:right;
}

.names span:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: radial-gradient(black 25%, transparent 25%) scroll repeat-x bottom left/5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='names col'>
  <span>Hamburger</span>
  <span>Hot Dogs</span>
  <span>Superman Hamburger</span>

</div>
<div class='prices col'>
  <span>$1.00</span>
  <span>$0.50</span>
  <span>$400.00</span>
</div>
```

### **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jacobgray/69t7rja0/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:table;` and `display: table-cell;` for the divs inside the list-elements and `border-bottom: Xpx dotted black;` for the dots.

```css
ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
ul li div {
  display: table-cell;
}
ul li div.food {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
ul li div.dots {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
}
ul li div.price {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="food">Spaghetti</div>
    <div class="dots">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="price">10.00$</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="food">Spaghetti</div>
    <div class="dots"></div>
    <div class="price">10.00$</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="food">Spaghetti</div>
    <div class="dots"></div>
    <div class="price">10.00$</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wrapper to set a fix width of your Name + Dots.

The css will look like this:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The HTML like this:

```
<div>
  <ul class="noDisc">
    <li>
      <div class="wrapper">
      <span>HAMBURGER </span>
      <span>...............................................................</span>
      </div>
      <span>$ 40.00</span>
    </li>
     <li>
      <div class="wrapper">
      <span>FRIED CHIKEN </span>
      <span>...............................................................</span>
      </div>
      <span>$ 13.00</span>
    </li>
     <li>
      <div class="wrapper">
      <span>STEAK ON A STICK </span>
      <span>...............................................................</span>
      </div>
      <span>$ 99.00</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Live sample:

[fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/6d3ca8hg/)

Comment: I like the no js answer here, but I don't like the fact that the prices are left aligned.  This means if the prices have a different number of characters (in your example they all have seven) it looks weird because the decimal places don't line up.

Any ideas on getting that to work with no javascript?

Comment: Do you mean if you have for example 138.31 and 1234.99 the dot of the numbers will be vertically aligned?

Comment: Ya exactly, like if I modify the amounts here the decimal places don't line up and it looks wrong, prices are usually right aligned: http://fiddle.jshell.net/6d3ca8hg/5/

I couldn't find a way to do that without javascript, but curious if you know a way?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I used what you had here and improved on it. This code is meant for woocommerce product items, but can be edited for whatever you need. $containerElement is the element you are measuring the width of.

```
/**
 * dotFiller
 * adds dynamic dot leaders between product title and count element (<mark>)
 * @return void
 */
var dotFiller = function(){
    var $containerElement = $('ul.products li.product.has-children h2'),
        df  = '<div class="df">.....................................................................</div>';
        $containerElement.each(function(i,el){
                var $el = $(el),
                    w   = $el.width(),
                    mw  = $el.find('mark').width(),
                    tw  = $el.find('span').width(),
                    dfw = (w - mw - tw) - 24;
                // if its not there, lets add it
                if (!$(el).has('.df').length){
                    $el.find('span').after(df);
                }
                $el.find('.df').css('width',dfw + "px");
        });
};
dotFiller();
```

With this code, you can update/ recalculate on resize like so :

```
$('window').on('resize',function(){ dotFiller(); });
```

And here is my css for the internal elements:

```
        mark {
            background-color: transparent;
            color: $secondary;
            display: inline-block; float: right;
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        div.df { 
            overflow: hidden; 
            display: inline-block; 
            margin-left: 10px; 
            position: relative; 
            top: 2px; 
            font-weight: normal; 
            opacity: 0.8; 
        }
```

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Use a div that has a flex spacer with a border-bottom to achieve easy leader dots... The flex layout seems to be the most elegant solution. No pseudo-elements, or left and right block display, etc... Very simple...

HTML

```
<div class="list-item">

    <div class="header-row">
      <h4>Menu</h4>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="list-item-row">
      <div class="left">Hamburger</div>
      <div class="dots"></div>
      <div class="right">$5.00</div>
    </div>

    <div class="list-item-row">
      <div class="left">Hamburger (XXL)</div>
      <div class="dots"></div>
      <div class="right">$7.50</div>
    </div>

    <div class="list-item-row">
      <div class="left">Milkshake</div>
      <div class="dots"></div>
      <div class="right">$3.50</div>
    </div>

    <div class="list-item-row">
      <div class="left">Pickle</div>
      <div class="dots"></div>
      <div class="right">Free</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Montserrat:400,700|Roboto:400,700");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: solid #424242 1px;
}

.list-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  background: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid #e0e0e0 1px;
}

.list-item-row,
.header-row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  .left,
  .right {
    font-family: "Roboto";
  }
  .right {
    color: blue;
  }
}

.dots {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  border-bottom: dotted 2px #b0b0b0;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em; 
}
```

See Codepen here => https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vVZmxB