# Is it possible to justify OLs in CSS? Text-align is not working

Tags: html, css, html-lists, justify

How do I align an ol so that it can look like this:

[Justified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf83F.png)

By simply "text-align: justify;" to the ol it looks like this:

[Not justified actually!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W875T.png)

Please and thank you :)

Comment: Frankly, I'd use a table.

Comment: please share some markup and css in a fiddle/codepen

Answer (score 0):

There is [a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8132612/1028949) that I used to create the leading dots in pure CSS. This is a CSS trick that puts dots behind everything, then covers up the dots behind the text using `background: white;`. If the background is a solid color, then this could work.

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  max-width: 20em;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

ol li:before {
  content: "...................................................";
  float: left;
  letter-spacing: 0.25em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 0;
}

ol span:first-child {
  background: white;
  padding-right: 0.33em;
}

ol span + span {
  background: white;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 0.33em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
 <li>
   <span>United States</span>
   <span>86%</span>
 </li>
 <li>
   <span>Canada</span>
   <span>5%</span>
 </li>
 <li>
   <span>UK</span>
   <span>4%</span>
 </li>
 <li>
   <span>Australia</span>
   <span>3%</span>
 </li>
 <li>
   <span>Germany</span>
   <span>2%</span>
 </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Paulie_D mentioned, you might want to consider using a simple table like this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>[Flag]</td>
      <td>[Name]</td>
      <td class="text-right">[Percentage]</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And you should make sure your table width is set to 100% of the container in your CSS file:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox version:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 0;
}
.list {
  display: flex;
}
.first {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  color: #2B91AF;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
.price {
  text-align: right;
  flex: 0 0 4em;
}
.first:after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: dotted 2px tomato;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>

  <li class="list">
    <i class='first'>Co-Pay:</i>
    <i class="price">$150.00</i>
  </li>
  <li class="list">
    <i class='first'>Pay:</i>
    <i class="price"> $5.00</i>
  </li>
  <li class="list">
    <i class='first'>Co-Pay: item</i>
    <i class="price"> $15.00</i>
  </li>
  <li class="list">
    <i class='first'>Co-Pay: great deal</i>
    <i class="price"> $1.00</i>
  </li>
</ul>
```