# How to put line between two texts (css or js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap UI and I have this code:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-ms-12" style="margin-top:15px !important;">
    <h2><strong>1 x Gourmet Tasting Menu for Two</strong><span class="pull-right">£96.00</span></h2>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Now I need to put dots (.) between `name` and `price` so something like this:

```
<h2><strong>1 x Gourmet Tasting Menu for Two</strong>..........................................................<span class="pull-right">£96.00</span></h2>
```

Screenshoot:[image]

What is the best way to do that? Some JS code or CSS code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create leading dots in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508732/create-leading-dots-in-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a CSS only solution you could use a pseudo element to create the dots with a border. The dots would run the whole width of the row. To hide the dots and allow them to have a *"dynamic"* width between the item text and price you add a background color to those elements that will cover up the extra dots. Normally the border would sit below all of this, so we pull the pseudo element up with relative positioning to hide it behind the text elements.

```css
strong,
span {
  padding: 0 5px;
  background-color: white;
}
span {
  float: right;
}
h2:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;  
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #333;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h2><strong>Text Here</strong><span>$9.99</span></h2>
```