# Leader dots separating columns in an HTML table

Tags: css-tables, leader

I want to create a table of contents in three columns with dots connecting them:
song.title.........  author...........  page

I tried to follow the example given by catchmyfame in
[Create leading dots in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508732/create-leading-dots-in-css)
but it's not working the way I expect. In fact, it's *differently* wrong when I display it as a local disk file than when I get it from my website.

Here's the URL of the page on my website:
http://conchord.org/xeno/ix.fsm.html

Here's my CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#maintable div {
    background: url('dot.gif') repeat-x bottom;
}
#maintable td div
{
    margin-right: 1ex;
}
#maintable td+td div {
    margin-left: 1ex;
}
#maintable td+td div,
#maintable td+td+td div {
    padding-right: 0;
}
#maintable td+td+td div  {
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #fff;
}
#maintable .nodots div,
    background: solid #fff;
    text-align: right;
}
#maintable div span {
    background-color: #fff;
}
#maintable td div span,
#maintable td div span.nodots {
    background-color: white;
}
table#maintable tr td+td+td { background-color: white; }
-->
</style>
```

And the start of my  section:

```
<body>
<h2>
Index of songs in <i>The Filksong Manual</i>
</h2>    
<table id="maintable">
 <tr>
  <td>
  <div><span>Ballad of Rhysling, The</span></div>
  </td>
  <td>
  <div><span>Roger Scime</span></div>
  </td>
  <td>
  <div><span class="nodots">92 </span></div>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

Note: I don't want the leader dots to quite reach the next column: I want them to stop about 2em before the start of the next column, hence the 2em padding in my CSS.

Comment: I am getting a 404 when fetching dot.gif.

Comment: Thank you. That explains why it was differently wrong on the website than on my local disk. I have uploaded dot.gif.

Now the question is why there are leader dots in the third column.

Comment: I also made some small changes in my CSS in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in your CSS:

```
TABLE TD DIV SPAN { background-color: white; }
```

That should eliminate the overlap.

Then I would remove the

```
#maintable td div
{
    margin-right: 1ex;
}
#maintable td+td div {
    margin-left: 1ex;
}
```

To remove the gaps. From there, it will likely be a series of minor tweaks to get the exact spacing (perhaps add some padding to the SPAN to avoid the dots from "touching".

Comment: That improved things, but I'm still getting leader in front of the right-aligned numbers.

Comment: The `td+td DIV` and `td DIV` still have `margin-left` and `margin-right` respectively which render the "empty" space you see.

Comment: I'm marking this question as answered. I'll start a new question with the remaining tweak I want to make.