# How to repeat character in HTML with responsive resizing?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create rows in a DIV where there are three pieces of information to display. A left align text, a right align text, and repeat character "." between the two

[image]

I tried this using the HTML below. But it is not working with a div for each piece.

```
 <div style="margin-bottom:5px"><!-- row 1 -->

    <div style="float:left;">Left</div> <!-- left column -->
    <div style="display: inline-block;">...</div> <!-- center column -->
    <div style="float:right;">Right</div> <!-- center column -->

  </div><!-- row 1 -->
```

I believe it most likely has to be done using just one div displaying one piece of text/string where the "." character gets repeated between the other two pieces of text. I cant figure it out so that the string changes with the DIV size - in order to keep it responsive.

Comment: use bootstrap style to make a responsive design.please refer this for more info:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/

Comment: What you want is called in typography a "leader".  [See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508732/create-leading-dots-in-css) There's actually a CSS spec for it, but it's part of the print media stuff and it's almost completely unsupported in browsers.

Comment: @Pointy That's definitely helpful although the answers seem pretty outdated. Though I noticed you didn't mark it as a dupe so I suppose that's just fine :)

Comment: @TylerRoper it's pretty old, yes, pre-flex. But the state of support for `leader()` in a CSS `content:` rule is still about the same. (It works in Flying Saucer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve that rather simply with flexbox and a dotted border.

```css
.row { display: flex; }

.center {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted black;
  margin: 0 4px 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="left">This is some longer left text</div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="right">This is some longer right text</div>
</div>
```

- Make parent `display: flex` so that children align side-by-side.
- Add `flex-grow: 1` to the `center` so that it fills empty space
- Add `border-bottom: 2px dotted black` to achieve your dotted line
- Add some margins to position and pad the dotted line properly

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this :

```
<div class="row>
    <div class="left">  Left  </div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="right"> Right </div>
</div>
```

And use flexbox to set the sizes:

```
.row           { display: flex; }
.left , .right { flex: 0 0 auto; } /* will not shrink or grow, with their default width set to auto */
.middle        { flex: 1 1 0; } /* will shrink/grow to fill all available space, with a default width of 0 */
```

Now, you could apply something like:

```
.middle {
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted currentColor;
    transform: translateY(-.4em); /* change to reposition vertically */
}
```

You can also add spacing by :

```
.left  { padding-right: 1em; }
.right { padding-left:  1em; }
```