# How can I justify groups of characters in list item text?

Tags: html, css

my in my HTML page my  look like this :

[image]

And I would like it to look like this :

[image]

**How I can do that with HTML and CSS ?**

```html
<ul>
    <li>Java &#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</li>
    <li>Python &#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</li>
    <li>HTML/CSS &#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</li>
    <li>SQL &#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</li>
    <li>JavaScript &#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</li>
    <li>PHP &#9733;&#9733;</li>
    <li>C &#9733;&#9733;</li>
    <li>Scala&#9733;</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you put the dots there because you want an arbitrary amount of dots between the text and the stars? OR, did you just use them to resemble the spacing you want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create leading dots in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508732/create-leading-dots-in-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the stars inside a span and consider a  table layout

```css
ul {
  display: table;
}

li {
  display: table-row;
}

li span {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Java <span>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span></li>
  <li>Python <span>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span></li>
  <li>HTML/CSS <span>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span></li>
  <li>SQL <span>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span></li>
  <li>JavaScript <span>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span></li>
  <li>PHP <span>&#9733;&#9733;</span></li>
  <li>C <span>&#9733;&#9733;</span></li>
  <li>Scala <span>&#9733;</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to isolate the text and the HTML entities in their own span elements. Then you can nest these new elements in `div`'s and use `flex` to align them. Then just define a width for your for the second span and you are good to go. I chose `80px` based on the longest rendered width of the text, which happened to be (HTML/CSS).

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

div>span:nth-child(1) {
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <span>Java</span>
      <span>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <span>Pyhton</span>
      <span>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <span>HTML/CSS</span>
      <span>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <span>SQL</span>
      <span>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <span>JavaScript</span>
      <span>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <span>PHP</span>
      <span>&#9733;&#9733;</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <span>C</span>
      <span>&#9733;&#9733;</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <span>Scala</span>
      <span>&#9733;</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```